# Filtering invalid utf8

Tags: command-line, text-processing, character-encoding, unicode

I have a text file in an unknown or mixed encoding. I want to see the lines that contain a byte sequence that is not valid UTF-8 (by piping the text file into some program). Equivalently, I want to filter out the lines that are valid UTF-8. In other words, I'm looking for `grep [notutf8]`.

An ideal solution would be portable, short and generalizable to other encodings, but if you feel the best way is to bake in the [definition of UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design), go ahead.

Comment: See also http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2004/Jun/29/UTF-8.regex for a possible regex.

Comment: @Mikel: or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/bulk-rename-or-correctly-display-files-with-special-characters/6464#6464 … I was hoping for something less clumsly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to use `grep`, you can do:

```
grep -axv '.*' file
```

in UTF-8 locales to get the lines that have at least an invalid UTF-8 sequence (this works with GNU Grep at least).

Comment: Except for `-a`, that's required to work by POSIX. However GNU `grep` at least fails to spot the UTF-8 encoded UTF-16 surrogate non-characters or codepoints above 0x10FFFF.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Conversely, the `-a` is needed by GNU `grep` (which isn't POSIX compliant, I assume). Concerning, the surrogate area and the codepoints above 0x10FFFF, this is a bug then (which could explain [that](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18454#146)). For this, adding `-P` should work with GNU `grep` 2.21 (but is slow); it is buggy at least [in Debian grep/2.20-4](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773560).

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the behaviour is unspecified in POSIX since `grep` is a text utility (only expected to work on text input), so I suppose GNU grep's behaviour is as valid as any here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I confirm that POSIX says: "The input files shall be text files." (though not in the description part, which is a bit misleading). This also means that in case of invalid sequences, the behavior is undefined by POSIX. Hence the need to know the implementation, such as GNU `grep` (whose intent is to regard invalid sequences as non-matching), and possible bugs.

Comment: I'm switching the accepted answer to this one (sorry, [Peter.O](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12545) because it's simple and works well for my primary use case, which is a heuristic to distinguish UTF-8 from other common encodings (especially 8-bit encodings). [Stéphane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175106) and [Peter.O](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12545) provide more accurate answers in terms of UTF-8 compliance.

Comment: This has been the best solution for removing finding invalid-UTF-8 characters for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

I think you probably want [`iconv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv). It's for converting between codesets and supports an absurd number of formats. For example, to strip anything not valid in UTF-8 you could use:

```
iconv -c -t UTF-8 < input.txt > output.txt
```

Without the -c option it'll report problems in converting to stderr, so with process direction could you save a list of these. Another way would be to strip the non-UTF8 stuff and then:

```
diff input.txt output.txt
```

for a list of where changes were made.

Comment: Ok, that's `iconv -c -t UTF-8 <input.txt | diff input.txt - | sed -ne 's/^< //p'`. It won't work as a pipeline, though, since you need to read the input twice (no, `tee` won't do, it might block depending on how much buffering `iconv` and `diff` do).

Comment: Random note: input & output may not be the same file or you will end up with an empty file

Comment: Or use process substitution if your shell supports it `diff <(iconv -c -t UTF-8 <input.txt) input.txt`

Comment: How do you do this and make the output to the same file as the input. I just did this and got a blank file iconv -c -t UTF-8 < input.txt > input.txt

Comment: Thanks.. This allow restoring broken utf-8 postgresql dump , but not discarding valid utf-8

Answer (score 23):

Edit: I've fixed a typo-bug in the regex.. It needed a '\x80` not *\80*.

The regex to filter out invalid UTF-8 forms, for **strict** adherance to UTF-8, is as follows

```
perl -l -ne '/
 ^( ([\x00-\x7F])              # 1-byte pattern
   |([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])   # 2-byte pattern
   |((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF])) # 3-byte pattern
   |((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2}))       # 4-byte pattern
  )*$ /x or print'
```

Output (of key lines.from *Test 1*):

```
Codepoint
=========  
00001000  Test=1 mode=strict               valid,invalid,fail=(1000,0,0)          
0000E000  Test=1 mode=strict               valid,invalid,fail=(D800,800,0)          
0010FFFF  mode=strict  test-return=(0,0)   valid,invalid,fail=(10F800,800,0)
```

---

Q. How does one create test data to test a regex which filters invalid Unicode ?
A. Create your own UTF-8 test algorithm, and break it's rules...
Catch-22.. *But then, how do you then test your test algorithm?*

The regex, above, has been tested (using `iconv` as the reference) for every integer value from `0x00000` to `0x10FFFF`..  This upper value being the [maximum integer value of a Unicode Codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History)

- [In November 2003 UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to four bytes covering only the range U+0000 to U+10FFFF, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History)`

According to this [wikipedia UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) page,.

- UTF-8 encodes each of the 1,112,064 code points in the Unicode character set, using one to four 8-bit bytes

This number (1,112,064) equates to a range `0x000000` to `0x10F7FF`, which is 0x0800 shy of the actual maximum integer-value for the highest Unicode Codepoint: `0x10FFFF`

This *block of integers* is missing from the Unicode Codepoints spectrum, because of the need for the UTF-16 encoding to *step beyond its original design intent* via a system called [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points).  A block of `0x0800` integers has been reserved to be used by UTF-16.. This block spans the range `0x00D800` to `0x00DFFF`. None of these inteters are legal Unicode values, and are therefore invalid UTF-8 values.

In **Test 1**, the `regex` has been tested against every number in the range of Unicode Codepoints, and it matches exectly the results of `iconv`  ..  ie. *0x010F7FF* valid values, and *0x000800* invalid values.

However, the issue now arises of, *How does the regex handle Out-Of-Range UTF-8 Value; above `0x010FFFF` (UTF-8 can extend to 6 bytes, with a maximum integer value of [0x7FFFFFFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design)?
To generate the necessary **non-unicode UTF-8 byte values*, I've used the following command:

```
  perl -C -e 'print chr 0x'$hexUTF32BE
```

To test their validity (in some fashion), I've used `Gilles'` UTF-8 regex...

```
  perl -l -ne '/
   ^( [\000-\177]                 # 1-byte pattern
     |[\300-\337][\200-\277]      # 2-byte pattern
     |[\340-\357][\200-\277]{2}   # 3-byte pattern
     |[\360-\367][\200-\277]{3}   # 4-byte pattern
     |[\370-\373][\200-\277]{4}   # 5-byte pattern
     |[\374-\375][\200-\277]{5}   # 6-byte pattern
    )*$ /x or print'
```

The output of 'perl's print chr' matches the filtering of Gilles' regex.. One reinforces the validity of the other..
I can't use `iconv` because it only handles the valid-Unicode Standard subset of the broader (original) UTF-8 standard...

The nunbers involved are rather large, so I've tested top-of-range, bottom-of-range, and several scans stepping by increments such as, 11111, 13579, 33333, 53441... The results all match, so now all that remains is to test the regex against these out-of-range UTF-8-style values (invalid for Unicode, and therefore also invalid for strict UTF-8 itself) ..

---

Here are the test modules:

```
[[ "$(locale charmap)" != "UTF-8" ]] && { echo "ERROR: locale must be UTF-8, but it is $(locale charmap)"; exit 1; }

# Testing the UTF-8 regex
#
# Tests to check that the observed byte-ranges (above) have
#  been  accurately observed and included in the test code and final regex. 
# =========================================================================
: 2 bytes; B2=0 #  run-test=1   do-not-test=0
: 3 bytes; B3=0 #  run-test=1   do-not-test=0
: 4 bytes; B4=0 #  run-test=1   do-not-test=0 

:   regex; Rx=1 #  run-test=1   do-not-test=0

           ((strict=16)); mode[$strict]=strict # iconv -f UTF-16BE  then iconv -f UTF-32BE beyond 0xFFFF)
           ((   lax=32)); mode[$lax]=lax       # iconv -f UTF-32BE  only)

          # modebits=$strict
                  # UTF-8, in relation to UTF-16 has invalid values
                  # modebits=$strict automatically shifts to modebits=$lax
                  # when the tested integer exceeds 0xFFFF
          # modebits=$lax 
                  # UTF-8, in relation to UTF-32, has no restrictione
           
           
           # Test 1 Sequentially tests a range of Big-Endian integers
           #      * Unicode Codepoints are a subset ofBig-Endian integers            
           #        ( based on 'iconv' -f UTF-32BE -f UTF-8 )    
           # Note: strict UTF-8 has a few quirks because of UTF-16
                    #    Set modebits=16 to "strictly" test the low range

             Test=1; modebits=$strict
           # Test=2; modebits=$lax
           # Test=3
              mode3wlo=$(( 1*4)) # minimum chars * 4 ( '4' is for UTF-32BE )
              mode3whi=$((10*4)) # minimum chars * 4 ( '4' is for UTF-32BE )


#########################################################################  

# 1 byte  UTF-8 values: Nothing to do; no complexities.

#########################################################################

#  2 Byte  UTF-8 values:  Verifying that I've got the right range values.
if ((B2==1)) ; then  
  echo "# Test 2 bytes for Valid UTF-8 values: ie. values which are in range"
  # =========================================================================
  time \
  for d1 in {194..223} ;do
      #     bin       oct  hex  dec
      # lo  11000010  302   C2  194
      # hi  11011111  337   DF  223
      B2b1=$(printf "%0.2X" $d1)
      #
      for d2 in {128..191} ;do
          #     bin       oct  hex  dec
          # lo  10000000  200   80  128
          # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
          B2b2=$(printf "%0.2X" $d2)
          #
          echo -n "${B2b1}${B2b2}" |
            xxd -p -u -r  |
              iconv -f UTF-8 >/dev/null || { 
                echo "ERROR: Invalid UTF-8 found: ${B2b1}${B2b2}"; exit 20; }
          #
      done
  done
  echo
  
  # Now do a negated test.. This takes longer, because there are more values.
  echo "# Test 2 bytes for Invalid values: ie. values which are out of range"
  # =========================================================================
  # Note: 'iconv' will treat a leading  \x00-\x7F as a valid leading single,
  #   so this negated test primes the first UTF-8 byte with values starting at \x80
  time \
  for d1 in {128..193} {224..255} ;do 
 #for d1 in {128..194} {224..255} ;do # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B2b2) 
      B2b1=$(printf "%0.2X" $d1)
      #
      for d2 in {0..127} {192..255} ;do
     #for d2 in {0..128} {192..255} ;do # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B2b1)
          B2b2=$(printf "%0.2X" $d2)
          #
          echo -n "${B2b1}${B2b2}" |
            xxd -p -u -r |
              iconv -f UTF-8 2>/dev/null && { 
                echo "ERROR: VALID UTF-8 found: ${B2b1}${B2b2}"; exit 21; }
          #
      done
  done
  echo
fi

#########################################################################

#  3 Byte  UTF-8 values:  Verifying that I've got the right range values.
if ((B3==1)) ; then  
  echo "# Test 3 bytes for Valid UTF-8 values: ie. values which are in range"
  # ========================================================================
  time \
  for d1 in {224..239} ;do
      #     bin       oct  hex  dec
      # lo  11100000  340   E0  224
      # hi  11101111  357   EF  239
      B3b1=$(printf "%0.2X" $d1)
      #
      if   [[ $B3b1 == "E0" ]] ; then
          B3b2range="$(echo {160..191})"
          #     bin       oct  hex  dec  
          # lo  10100000  240   A0  160  
          # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
      elif [[ $B3b1 == "ED" ]] ; then
          B3b2range="$(echo {128..159})"
          #     bin       oct  hex  dec  
          # lo  10000000  200   80  128  
          # hi  10011111  237   9F  159
      else
          B3b2range="$(echo {128..191})"
          #     bin       oct  hex  dec
          # lo  10000000  200   80  128
          # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
      fi
      # 
      for d2 in $B3b2range ;do
          B3b2=$(printf "%0.2X" $d2)
          echo "${B3b1} ${B3b2} xx"
          #
          for d3 in {128..191} ;do
              #     bin       oct  hex  dec
              # lo  10000000  200   80  128
              # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
              B3b3=$(printf "%0.2X" $d3)
              #
              echo -n "${B3b1}${B3b2}${B3b3}" |
                xxd -p -u -r  |
                  iconv -f UTF-8 >/dev/null || { 
                    echo "ERROR: Invalid UTF-8 found: ${B3b1}${B3b2}${B3b3}"; exit 30; }
              #
          done
      done
  done
  echo

  # Now do a negated test.. This takes longer, because there are more values.
  echo "# Test 3 bytes for Invalid values: ie. values which are out of range"
  # =========================================================================
  # Note: 'iconv' will treat a leading  \x00-\x7F as a valid leading single,
  #   so this negated test primes the first UTF-8 byte with values starting at \x80
  #
  # real     26m28.462s \ 
  # user     27m12.526s  | stepping by 2
  # sys      13m11.193s /
  #
  # real    239m00.836s \
  # user    225m11.108s  | stepping by 1
  # sys     120m00.538s /
  #
  time \
  for d1 in {128..223..1} {240..255..1} ;do 
 #for d1 in {128..224..1} {239..255..1} ;do # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B2b2,$B3b3) 
      B3b1=$(printf "%0.2X" $d1)
      #
      if   [[ $B3b1 == "E0" ]] ; then
          B3b2range="$(echo {0..159..1} {192..255..1})"
         #B3b2range="$(> {192..255..1})" # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B3b1,$B3b3)
      elif [[ $B3b1 == "ED" ]] ; then
          B3b2range="$(echo {0..127..1} {160..255..1})"
         #B3b2range="$(echo {0..128..1} {160..255..1})" # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B3b1,$B3b3)
      else
          B3b2range="$(echo {0..127..1} {192..255..1})"
         #B3b2range="$(echo {0..128..1} {192..255..1})" # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B3b1,$B3b3)
      fi
      for d2 in $B3b2range ;do
          B3b2=$(printf "%0.2X" $d2)
          echo "${B3b1} ${B3b2} xx"
          #
          for d3 in {0..127..1} {192..255..1} ;do
         #for d3 in {0..128..1} {192..255..1} ;do # force a valid UTF-8 (needs $B2b1)
              B3b3=$(printf "%0.2X" $d3)
              #
              echo -n "${B3b1}${B3b2}${B3b3}" |
                xxd -p -u -r |
                  iconv -f UTF-8 2>/dev/null && { 
                    echo "ERROR: VALID UTF-8 found: ${B3b1}${B3b2}${B3b3}"; exit 31; }
              #
          done
      done
  done
  echo

fi

#########################################################################

#  Brute force testing in the Astral Plane will take a VERY LONG time..
#  Perhaps selective testing is more appropriate, now that the previous tests 
#     have panned out okay... 
#  
#  4 Byte  UTF-8 values:
if ((B4==1)) ; then  
  echo "# Test 4 bytes for Valid UTF-8 values: ie. values which are in range"
  # ==================================================================
  # real    58m18.531s \
  # user    56m44.317s  | 
  # sys     27m29.867s /
  time \
  for d1 in {240..244} ;do
      #     bin       oct  hex  dec
      # lo  11110000  360   F0  240
      # hi  11110100  364   F4  244  -- F4 encodes some values greater than 0x10FFFF;
      #                                    such a sequence is invalid.
      B4b1=$(printf "%0.2X" $d1)
      #
      if   [[ $B4b1 == "F0" ]] ; then
        B4b2range="$(echo {144..191})" ## f0 90 80 80  to  f0 bf bf bf
        #     bin       oct  hex  dec          010000  --  03FFFF 
        # lo  10010000  220   90  144  
        # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
        #                            
      elif [[ $B4b1 == "F4" ]] ; then
        B4b2range="$(echo {128..143})" ## f4 80 80 80  to  f4 8f bf bf
        #     bin       oct  hex  dec          100000  --  10FFFF 
        # lo  10000000  200   80  128  
        # hi  10001111  217   8F  143  -- F4 encodes some values greater than 0x10FFFF;
        #                                    such a sequence is invalid.
      else
        B4b2range="$(echo {128..191})" ## fx 80 80 80  to  f3 bf bf bf
        #     bin       oct  hex  dec          0C0000  --  0FFFFF
        # lo  10000000  200   80  128          0A0000
        # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
      fi
      #
      for d2 in $B4b2range ;do
          B4b2=$(printf "%0.2X" $d2)
          #
          for d3 in {128..191} ;do
              #     bin       oct  hex  dec
              # lo  10000000  200   80  128
              # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
              B4b3=$(printf "%0.2X" $d3)
              echo "${B4b1} ${B4b2} ${B4b3} xx"
              #
              for d4 in {128..191} ;do
                  #     bin       oct  hex  dec
                  # lo  10000000  200   80  128
                  # hi  10111111  277   BF  191
                  B4b4=$(printf "%0.2X" $d4)
                  #
                  echo -n "${B4b1}${B4b2}${B4b3}${B4b4}" |
                    xxd -p -u -r  |
                      iconv -f UTF-8 >/dev/null || { 
                        echo "ERROR: Invalid UTF-8 found: ${B4b1}${B4b2}${B4b3}${B4b4}"; exit 40; }
                  #
              done
          done
      done
  done
  echo "# Test 4 bytes for Valid UTF-8 values: END"
  echo
fi

########################################################################
# There is no test (yet) for negated range values in the astral plane. #  
#                           (all negated range values must be invalid) #
#  I won't bother; This was mainly for me to ge the general feel of    #     
#   the tests, and the final test below should flush anything out..    #
# Traversing the intire UTF-8 range takes quite a while...             #
#   so no need to do it twice (albeit in a slightly different manner)  #
########################################################################

################################
### The construction of:    ####
###  The Regular Expression ####
###      (de-construction?) ####
################################

#     BYTE 1                BYTE 2       BYTE 3      BYTE 4 
# 1: [\x00-\x7F]
#    ===========
#    ([\x00-\x7F])
#
# 2: [\xC2-\xDF]           [\x80-\xBF]
#    =================================
#    ([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])
# 
# 3: [\xE0]                [\xA0-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]   
#    [\xED]                [\x80-\x9F]  [\x80-\xBF]
#    [\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF]  [\x80-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]
#    ==============================================
#    ((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF]))
#
# 4  [\xF0]                [\x90-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]    
#    [\xF1-\xF3]           [\x80-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]
#    [\xF4]                [\x80-\x8F]  [\x80-\xBF]  [\x80-\xBF]
#    ===========================================================
#    ((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2}))
#
# The final regex
# ===============
# 1-4:  (([\x00-\x7F])|([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])|((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF]))|((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2})))
# 4-1:  (((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2}))|((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF]))|([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])|([\x00-\x7F]))


#######################################################################
#  The final Test; for a single character (multi chars to follow)     #  
#   Compare the return code of 'iconv' against the 'regex'            #
#   for the full range of 0x000000 to 0x10FFFF                        #
#                                                                     #     
#  Note; this script has 3 modes:                                     #
#        Run this test TWICE, set each mode Manually!                 #     
#                                                                     #     
#     1. Sequentially test every value from 0x000000 to 0x10FFFF      #     
#     2. Throw a spanner into the works! Force random byte patterns   #     
#     2. Throw a spanner into the works! Force random longer strings  #     
#        ==============================                               #     
#                                                                     #     
#  Note: The purpose of this routine is to determine if there is any  #
#        difference how 'iconv' and 'regex' handle the same data      #  
#                                                                     #     
#######################################################################
if ((Rx==1)) ; then
  # real    191m34.826s
  # user    158m24.114s
  # sys      83m10.676s
  time { 
  invalCt=0
  validCt=0
   failCt=0
  decBeg=$((0x00110000)) # incement by decimal integer
  decMax=$((0x7FFFFFFF)) # incement by decimal integer
  # 
  for ((CPDec=decBeg;CPDec<=decMax;CPDec+=13247)) ;do
      ((D==1)) && echo "=========================================================="
      #
      # Convert decimal integer '$CPDec' to Hex-digits; 6-long  (dec2hex)
      hexUTF32BE=$(printf '%0.8X\n' $CPDec)  # hexUTF32BE

      # progress count  
      if (((CPDec%$((0x1000)))==0)) ;then
          ((Test>2)) && echo
          echo "$hexUTF32BE  Test=$Test mode=${mode[$modebits]}            "
      fi
      if   ((Test==1 || Test==2 ))
      then # Test 1. Sequentially test every value from 0x000000 to 0x10FFFF
          #
          if   ((Test==2)) ; then
              bits=32
              UTF8="$( perl -C -e 'print chr 0x'$hexUTF32BE |
                perl -l -ne '/^(  [\000-\177]
                                | [\300-\337][\200-\277]
                                | [\340-\357][\200-\277]{2}
                                | [\360-\367][\200-\277]{3}
                                | [\370-\373][\200-\277]{4}
                                | [\374-\375][\200-\277]{5}
                               )*$/x and print' |xxd -p )"
              UTF8="${UTF8%0a}"
              [[ -n "$UTF8" ]] \
                    && rcIco32=0 || rcIco32=1
                       rcIco16=

          elif ((modebits==strict && CPDec<=$((0xFFFF)))) ;then
              bits=16
              UTF8="$( echo -n "${hexUTF32BE:4}" |
                xxd -p -u -r |
                  iconv -f UTF-16BE -t UTF-8 2>/dev/null)" \
                    && rcIco16=0 || rcIco16=1  
                       rcIco32=
          else
              bits=32
              UTF8="$( echo -n "$hexUTF32BE" |
                xxd -p -u -r |
                  iconv -f UTF-32BE -t UTF-8 2>/dev/null)" \
                    && rcIco32=0 || rcIco32=1
                       rcIco16=
          fi
          # echo "1 mode=${mode[$modebits]}-$bits  rcIconv: (${rcIco16},${rcIco32})  $hexUTF32BE "
          #
          #
          #
          if ((${rcIco16}${rcIco32}!=0)) ;then
              # 'iconv -f UTF-16BE' failed produce a reliable UTF-8
              if ((bits==16)) ;then
                  ((D==1)) &&           echo "bits-$bits rcIconv: error    $hexUTF32BE .. 'strict' failed, now trying 'lax'"
                  #  iconv failed to create a  'srict' UTF-8 so   
                  #      try UTF-32BE to get a   'lax' UTF-8 pattern    
                  UTF8="$( echo -n "$hexUTF32BE" |
                    xxd -p -u -r |
                      iconv -f UTF-32BE -t UTF-8 2>/dev/null)" \
                        && rcIco32=0 || rcIco32=1
                  #echo "2 mode=${mode[$modebits]}-$bits  rcIconv: (${rcIco16},${rcIco32})  $hexUTF32BE "
                  if ((rcIco32!=0)) ;then
                      ((D==1)) &&               echo -n "bits-$bits rcIconv: Cannot gen UTF-8 for: $hexUTF32BE"
                      rcIco32=1
                  fi
              fi
          fi
          # echo "3 mode=${mode[$modebits]}-$bits  rcIconv: (${rcIco16},${rcIco32})  $hexUTF32BE "
          #
          #
          #
          if ((rcIco16==0 || rcIco32==0)) ;then
              # 'strict(16)' OR 'lax(32)'... 'iconv' managed to generate a UTF-8 pattern  
                  ((D==1)) &&       echo -n "bits-$bits rcIconv: pattern* $hexUTF32BE"
                  ((D==1)) &&       if [[ $bits == "16" && $rcIco32 == "0" ]] ;then 
                  echo " .. 'lax' UTF-8 produced a pattern"
              else
                  echo
              fi
               # regex test
              if ((modebits==strict)) ;then
                 #rxOut="$(echo -n "$UTF8" |perl -l -ne '/^(([\x00-\x7F])|([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])|((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF]))|((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2})))*$/ or print' )"
                                     rxOut="$(echo -n "$UTF8" |
                  perl -l -ne '/^( ([\x00-\x7F])             # 1-byte pattern
                                  |([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])  # 2-byte pattern
                                  |((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF]))  # 3-byte pattern
                                  |((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2}))        # 4-byte pattern
                                 )*$ /x or print' )"
               else
                  if ((Test==2)) ;then
                      rx="$(echo -n "$UTF8" |perl -l -ne '/^([\000-\177]|[\300-\337][\200-\277]|[\340-\357][\200-\277]{2}|[\360-\367][\200-\277]{3}|[\370-\373][\200-\277]{4}|[\374-\375][\200-\277]{5})*$/ and print')"
                      [[ "$UTF8" != "$rx" ]] && rxOut="$UTF8" || rxOut=
                      rx="$(echo -n "$rx" |sed -e "s/\(..\)/\1 /g")"  
                  else 
                      rxOut="$(echo -n "$UTF8" |perl -l -ne '/^([\000-\177]|[\300-\337][\200-\277]|[\340-\357][\200-\277]{2}|[\360-\367][\200-\277]{3}|[\370-\373][\200-\277]{4}|[\374-\375][\200-\277]{5})*$/ or print' )"
                  fi
              fi
              if [[ "$rxOut" == "" ]] ;then
                ((D==1)) &&           echo "        rcRegex: ok"
                  rcRegex=0
              else
                  ((D==1)) &&           echo -n "bits-$bits rcRegex: error    $hexUTF32BE .. 'strict' failed,"
                  ((D==1)) &&           if [[  "12" == *$Test* ]] ;then 
                                            echo # "  (codepoint) Test $Test" 
                                        else
                                            echo
                                        fi
                  rcRegex=1
              fi
          fi
          #
      elif [[ $Test == 2 ]]
      then # Test 2. Throw a randomizing spanner into the works! 
          #          Then test the  arbitary bytes ASIS
          #
          hexLineRand="$(echo -n "$hexUTF32BE" |
            sed -re "s/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/\1\n\2\n\3\n\4\n\5\n\6\n\7\n\8/" |
              sort -R |
                tr -d '\n')"
          # 
      elif [[ $Test == 3 ]]
      then # Test 3. Test single UTF-16BE bytes in the range 0x00000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF
          #
          echo "Test 3 is not properly implemented yet.. Exiting"
          exit 99 
      else
          echo "ERROR: Invalid mode"
          exit
      fi
      #
      #
      if ((Test==1 || Test=2)) ;then
          if ((modebits==strict && CPDec<=$((0xFFFF)))) ;then
              ((rcIconv=rcIco16))
          else
              ((rcIconv=rcIco32))
          fi
          if ((rcRegex!=rcIconv)) ;then
              [[ $Test != 1 ]] && echo
              if ((rcRegex==1)) ;then
                  echo "ERROR: 'regex' ok, but NOT 'iconv': ${hexUTF32BE} "
              else
                  echo "ERROR: 'iconv' ok, but NOT 'regex': ${hexUTF32BE} "
              fi
              ((failCt++));
          elif ((rcRegex!=0)) ;then
            # ((invalCt++)); echo -ne "$hexUTF32BE  exit-codes $${rcIco16}${rcIco32}=,$rcRegex\t: $(printf "%0.8X\n" $invalCt)\t$hexLine$(printf "%$(((mode3whi*2)-${#hexLine}))s")\r"
              ((invalCt++)) 
          else
              ((validCt++)) 
          fi
          if   ((Test==1)) ;then
              echo -ne "$hexUTF32BE "    "mode=${mode[$modebits]}  test-return=($rcIconv,$rcRegex)   valid,invalid,fail=($(printf "%X" $validCt),$(printf "%X" $invalCt),$(printf "%X" $failCt))          \r"
          else 
              echo -ne "$hexUTF32BE $rx mode=${mode[$modebits]} test-return=($rcIconv,$rcRegex)  val,inval,fail=($(printf "%X" $validCt),$(printf "%X" $invalCt),$(printf "%X" $failCt))\r"
          fi
      fi
  done
  } # End time
fi
exit
```

Comment: The main problem with my regexp is that it allowed some forbidden sequences such as `\300\200` (really bad: that's code point 0 not expressed with a null byte!). I think your regexp rejects them correctly.

Answer (score 7):

I find `uconv` (in `icu-devtools` package in Debian) useful to inspect UTF-8 data:

```
$ print '\\xE9 \xe9 \u20ac \ud800\udc00 \U110000' |
    uconv --callback escape-c -t us
\xE9 \xE9 \u20ac \xED\xA0\x80\xED\xB0\x80 \xF4\x90\x80\x80
```

(The `\x`s help spotting the invalid characters (except for the false positive voluntarily introduced with a literal `\xE9` above)).

(plenty of other nice usages).

Comment: I think `recode` can be used similarly - except that *I think* it should fail if asked to translate an invalid multibyte sequence. I'm not sure though; it won't fail for `print...|recode u8..u8/x4` for example *(which just does a hexdump as you do above)* because it doesn't do anything but `iconv data data`, but it *does fail* like `recode u8..u2..u8/x4` because it translates then prints. But I don't know enough about it to be sure - and there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: If I have a file, say, `test.txt`. How should I suppose to find the invalid character using your solution? What does `us` in your code mean?

Comment: @Hao, `us` means United States, that is short for ASCII. It converts the input into a ASCII one where the non-ASCII characters are converted to `\uXXXX` notation and the non-characters to `\xXX`.

Comment: Where should I put my file to use your script? Is the last line in the code block the output of your code? It is a little confusing to me.

Answer (score 4):

Python has had a [built-in `unicode` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) since version 2.0.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        unicode(line, 'utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

In Python 3, `unicode` has been folded into [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq). It needs to be passed a [bytes-like object](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object), here the underlying [`buffer`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer) objects for the [standard descriptors](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
for line in sys.stdin.buffer:
    try:
        str(line, 'utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
```

Comment: The `python 2` one fails to flag UTF-8 encoded UTF-16 surrogate non-characters (at least with 2.7.6).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Dammit. Thanks. I've only run nominal tests so far, I'll run Peter's test battery later.

Answer (score 2):

I came across similar problem (detail in "Context" section) and arrived with following [ftfy_line_by_line.py](https://gist.github.com/gwpl/427f76c571c41357e10a5153b9f62d17) solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ftfy, sys
with open(sys.argv[1], mode='rt', encoding='utf8', errors='replace') as f:
  for line in f:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(ftfy.fix_text(line).encode('utf8', 'replace'))
    #print(ftfy.fix_text(line).rstrip().decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="replace"))
```

Using encode+replace + [ftfy](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) to auto-fix [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and other corrections.

## Context

I've collected >10GiB CSV of basic filesystem metadata using following [gen_basic_files_metadata.csv.sh](https://gist.github.com/gwpl/20aa3c8c1daa98619cd8f733a0326cb5) script, running essentially:

```
find "${path}" -type f -exec stat --format="%i,%Y,%s,${hostname},%m,%n" "{}" \;
```

The **trouble** I had was with **inconsistent encoding of filenames** across file systems, causing `UnicodeDecodeError` when processing further with python applications ([csvsql](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvsql.html) to be more specific).

Therefore I applied above ftfy script, and it took

Please note [ftfy](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) is pretty slow, processing those >10GiB took:

```
real    147m35.182s
user    146m14.329s
sys     2m8.713s
```

while sha256sum for comparison:

```
real    6m28.897s
user    1m9.273s
sys     0m6.210s
```

on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz + 16GiB RAM (and data on external drive)

Comment: And yes, I know that this find command will not properly encode filenames containing quotes according to csv standard