# rename character "â" of directory name?

Tags: find, rename, xargs

I'm trying to rename rename character `â` of directory name to be blank. For example, directory with name `how-â8093-to`.

This is the command I use, including some other modification

```
find . -type d | xargs rename 's/â//'
```

but still not works.

Comment: any error message?

Comment: no error message, but it simply do nothing

Comment: Related question: [bulk rename files with special characters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/s/6460/).

Answer (score 2):

When using `find` to operate on files you should always try to use the `-exec` function rather than `xargs` wherever possible because it will side-step a lot of potential issues with argument quoting. Particularly in the case of file names with weird characters, this is very important.

Try the following command:

```
find . -type d -name '*â*' -execdir rename 'â' '' {} \;
```

This will find everything just the way you were before except it will use find to also filter by name for only files that have â in the name (since it would be pointless to run the rename command on non-matching files) and then run `rename`  on them each individually from the directory where they are found.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to remove that character from one file and can't do it?  Can you type `mv how-`<kbd>tab</kbd>`how-8093-to` or `mv how-?8093-to how-8093-to`?

Comment: yes, I can `mv`, but I prefer `rename` for renaming too many files

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work-around using complement character classes, e.g.:

```
find . -type d | xargs rename 's/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]//'
```

However, on a Ubuntu 10.04 system I can't reproduce your issue with your example filename and `rename`. Perhaps something is wrong with your perl installation or locales?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how version of rename (I am using util-linux version) are you using but on my Fedora 15 works with:

```
rename 'â' '' how-â8093-to
```

From rename manual:

```
NAME
   rename - Rename files

SYNOPSIS
       rename from to file...
       rename -V

DESCRIPTION
       rename will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of from in their name by to.
```

I cannot read anything about the sed like syntax you are using.