# .DELETE_ON_ERROR behavior with make and pipelines

Tags: bash, pipe, make, exit

The `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` target will tell make to delete a target if a rule fails. But this doesn't work for pipelines, because the exit status value `$?` holds the value of the last program in the pipeline. As an example, the following makefile will not delete the newly created file *foo*.

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
foo:
    false | true > foo
```

Is there a way to get make to consider the rule as having failed if any of the programs in the pipeline fail (i.e., if there's a non-zero value in any of the elements of the `$PIPESTATUS` array)?

Comment: Related: [Get exit code of process that's piped to another](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14270)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using bash, you can also set the pipefail option globally. I have this once at the start of my makefiles and it catches errors even in the middle of a pipe:

```
# Make sure any errors in the middle of a pipe cause the build to fail
SHELL=/bin/bash -e -o pipefail
```

(Changed from /bin/sh to /bin/bash based on MadScientist's comment)

Comment: Good point, MadScientist. I'll update my response to reflect your comment. (And discuss with my teammates internally.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure your makefile will have `bash` as its shell, you could try setting the pipefail option:

```
SHELL=bash
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
foo:
    set -o pipefail; false | true > foo
```

Since each line of a rule runs in a separate shell instance, you'll have to add `set -o pipefail` to each line you want to apply this to.

If you want it to work on any POSIX `sh` (and not just `bash`), the answer is much more involved.

Comment: This works, but boy is it ugly to add it to every line that contains a pipeline.

Comment: @lorin: You could clean it up a little with a Make variable -- e.g. `PF=set -o pipefail;` after which you can do `$(PF) false | true > foo`.