# Check for failure of piped command

Tags: pipe, exit-status

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get exit code of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-code-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

If I pipe the output of one command into another, is there a way for me to check explicitly whether the first command failed?

For example, if `prog` processes a file and outputs to STDOUT:

```
prog file1 | cmp - file2
```

is there a way to check if `prog` explicitly failed or succeeded (by return code)? I want to avoid the use of temporary files, and don't want to rely on the output of the second command; so, for the example above, I want to avoid examining the output of `cmp` to determine if `prog` failed (if there is no affirmative answer to my question, I'll just fall back to doing precisely that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `set -o pipefail`.

From the Bash manpage:

```
pipefail

If set, the return value of a  pipeline  is  the value  of
the  last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status,
or zero if all  commands in  the pipeline exit successfully.
This option is disabled by default.
```

Comment: also have a look at `PIPESTATUS`