# tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Tags: gzip, tar

```
root@server # tar fcz bkup.tar.gz /home/foo/
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

How can I solve this problem and keep the `/` on file names ?

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: It is not a problem. You **do not want** leading slashes in a tar archive. Seriously. If you want to extract an archive to your system root, specify `-C /` when extracting it.

Comment: I also see `tar: Removing leading \`/' from hard link targets`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use the `--absolute-names` or `-P` option to disable this feature.

```bash
tar fczP bkup.tar.gz /home/foo
tar fcz bkup.tar.gz --absolute-names /home/foo
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but be aware, that **in most cases, this is not what you want**, cause it results in an archive that extracts in complete paths!

Comment: Using the `-C /` option as described in @Marcus' answer will git rid of the STDERR message if that is your primary goal.

Comment: Most of the time this is not what a user wants, simply because most of them don't read the manual until they need to (ain't nobody got time for that). So, it would be wise to, at least, expand your answer, warning people not to do this unless they are absolutely sure they understand what's the effect of it. Especially being accepted as an answer.

Comment: @MladenB. `tar` also removes the leading slash by default when extracting. So even if you use this option when creating the archive, it won't be a problem unless the user also uses it when extracting.

Comment: Archives with absolute locations are a security risk. Attackers could use such archives to trick users into installing files in critical system locations.

Comment: @A.B. That assumes you're making the archive for public distribution. If you're doing it for an internal backup, it's not as much of a concern.

Comment: @A.B. And your point has already been made in Mark Adler's answer.

Answer (score 142):

If you want to get rid of "Removing leading `/' from member names" being printed to STDERR, but still want to leave off those leading slashes as tar wisely does by default, I saw an excellent solution [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bin-tar-removing-leading-%60-from-member-names-269508/) by commenter timsoft.

The solution involves using -C option to change directory to the root (/), then specifying the file tree to archive **without** a leading slash, because now you only need a relative path.  This does the same thing as a normal tar create command, but no stripping is needed:

```
tar fcz bkup.tar.gz -C / home/foo/
```

Comment: It won't work with incremental backups. But a good answer.

Comment: It also doesn't work if you want to tar files denoted by shell-expansion (e.g. `tar c -C / home/foo/*`), because the shell doesn't know about the changed root. But still a good answer for other cases.

Comment: `-C /` doesn't work for me, period. It doesn't prevent the stderr for me.

Comment: @A-B-B make sure the path following -C / is relative.

Comment: Will this approach work if a user doesn't have permissions on the root directory?

Answer (score 111):

That's actually a feature, not a problem. Archives with absolute locations are a security risk. Attackers could use such archives to trick users into installing files in critical system locations.

Yes, you could use `-P`.  But what's wrong with allowing tar to remove the forward slash, and simply requiring the user of the archive to explicitly do the extraction in the root directory? Then they're consciously impacting critical system locations, and can't do it by accident.

Comment: Sometimes features are problems. I found this thread after setting up a backup script that would email on a non-zero exit status from `tar`. This particular message was causing `tar` to exit with a status of `1`, which was causing me to receive false email alerts on successful backups, simply because `tar` was writing this message to STDERR. I fixed this issue by using my own tweaked version of @Marcus's solution: `cd /path/to/network/share && tar -cJf scripts.backup.tar.xz -C / home/user/scripts 2>/dev/null || [send an email alert]`

Comment: I think there are some use cases for using `-P` - for example, if you're providing some kind of filesystem snapshotting feature in FUSE. Some of the time you may want to untar a snapshot in a specific directory rather than the `cwd` from the perspective of the user.

Answer (score 54):

One month late, but I found the most appropriate solution for my case (in a shell script) is to go to the parent directory and execute the command there.

```
cd /var/www/
tar -czf mysite.gz mysite
```

Instead of:

```
tar -czf /var/www/mysite.gz /var/www/mysite
```

Comment: Indeed you could have done it using:

tar -zcvf  mysite.gz -C /var/www/ mysite/

The benefit of this is that you can execute it from any directory

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all.  It's something different that could be done. … … … Like: Q: How do I get from Los Angeles to New York?  A: Go to San Francisco instead.

Comment: I agree with @G-Man . This will result in a tar file with a completely different directory structure. In some cases, that directory structure is actually more appropriate in the first place, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: And you can just do this in a bash script. And at the end of the bash function can just do cd - and that takes you to wherever you were before the script. And can just copy files into the directory via the bash script, before you zip them. Then when you unzip them they just appear in that given directory. Then you can just copy them back to wherever you want in the bash script as well. Its simple this way, works and it avoids the complexity of the tarball command. Comments welcome.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I did it by using brute force method: `2>&1 | grep -v  "Removing leading"`.

For example:

```
tar -cf "$BKUPDIR/${BKUPFILE}.tar" --overwrite --exclude '.*' --one-file-system "$SRCDIR" 2>&1 | grep -v  "Removing leading"
```

Comment: The problem with this is it hides the error code. So if you want to check the error code from tar in a bash script, then it won't return 0 on success.

Comment: @staticx, the error code is 0 regardless.

Comment: @A-B-B My `tar` command may return `2` on fatal error.

Comment: @Brian you can use $PIPESTATUS to get the exit code. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another/73180#73180

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `-C` for path only which would prevent compressing with complete paths:

```
root@server # tar fcz bkup.tar.gz -C /home/ foo/
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with:

`cd /home/foo && tar czf ~/backup.tar.gz .`

that way you aren't trying to put absolute paths into the tar archive in the first place. If you want untar it at the root of the file system you just

`cd / && tar xzf backupt.tar.gz` after transferring it.

Answer (score 2):

The path of the archive when specified causes this informational message, you can do the following to resolve it:

```
tar -zvcf /tmp/mike.tar.gz -P /tmp/mike
```

or

```
tar -zvcf mike.tar.gz -P /tmp/mike
```

or

```
tar -zvcf mike.tar.gz /tmp/mike
```

Note: it is not an error, just informational.

Answer (score -1):

its not a feature, its a bug. removing absolute paths creates an unextractable archive if path data gets fooey somehow. tar spits out the error and refuses to extract anything. better to use tardy to filter the path first.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. What exactly do you mean with "fooey"? Which error have you experienced after extracting a TAR archive that had the leading `/` removed during creation? To what TAR versions does your comment apply? With GNU tar, I certainly haven't experienced any problems during extraction.