# exit a script if an ls line did not find any match

Tags: shell-script, ls, exit

I am writing this script that have this line:

`ls -lrt /dir1/dir2/filename*.txt | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}' | read variable`

What I wanted is to exit the script (without using if-statement) if it does not find any match.

Comment: You can certainly do it and I see a way as seen from here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068942/1742825. However, you need to add more details so that it can be modified to suit your requirements.

Comment: Why do you have a requirement that `if` statements can't be used? Can you use other conditional operators such as `||`?

Comment: yeah, I can use double pipe I tried this `ls -lrt /dir1/dir2/filename*.txt | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}' | read variable || echo "exiting..."; exit` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

### How to write this command

This particular task doesn't call for a pipe.

In zsh:

```
a=(/dir1/dir2/filename*.txt(Nom[1]))
if ((! #a)); then
  echo >&2 "No file matches /dir1/dir2/filename*.txt"
  exit 2
fi
variable=$a[1]
```

or, to exit the script automatically if the glob doesn't match:

```
set -e
a=(/dir1/dir2/filename*.txt(om[1]))
variable=$a[1]
```

Other shells don't have a built-in feature to find the most recent file. Calling `ls` is reasonable provided that your file names only contain printable characters other than newlines, but don't pass the `-l` option and then parse out all but the name, that's gratuitously complex and fragile (breaks on spaces, in particular). Also, take the first match of the `-t` sort, that's faster than taking the last match of the `-tr` sort. The straightforward approach:

```
variable=$(ls -td /dir1/dir2/filename*.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)
if [ -z "$variable" ]; then
  echo >&2 "No file matches /dir1/dir2/filename*.txt"
  exit 2
fi
```

### Handling pipes

If you want to abort your script when the left-hand side of a pipeline fails (i.e. exits with a nonzero status or due to a signal), in ksh93 and bash, you can set the `pipefail` option and exit if the status of the pipeline is nonzero.

```
set -e -o pipefail
somecommand | filter
echo "somecommand succeeded"
```

or

```
set -o pipefail
if ! somecommand | filter; then
  echo >&2 "somecommand or filter failed"
  exit 2
fi
```

Zsh doesn't have a `pipefail` option, but you can retrieve the status code of each component of the pipeline in the `pipestatus` array.

```
somecommand | filter
if ((pipestatus[1])); then
  echo >&2 "somecommand failed"
  exit 2
fi
```

In other shells, the status of the pipeline is the status of the right-hand command. There's no direct way to retrieve the status of the left-hand command. See [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another/14290#14290) for some possible workarounds.

Beware that `filter` should read the whole output of `somecommand`, otherwise you need to handle the case when `somecommand` dies of a [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE#SIGPIPE).

If you want to act based on whether `somecommand` produces any output, rather than based on its exit status, you can use [`ifne`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) from [Joey Hess's moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). Note that most systems don't have these utilities installed by default.

Comment: `touch 2 ; sleep 1 ; touch 1; for sh in mksh dash yash posh bash zsh 'busybox ash'; do command -p $sh -c '[ 1 -nt 2 ] || echo $0'; done 2>/dev/null` prints only `posh`. So it might be more correct to say *`posh`  doesn't have a built-in feature to find the most recent file.* And the most direct way to handle the return status of a pipe's left-hand command is to directly handle the return status of a pipe's left-hand command, signalling the parent shell as necessary - this is true in any shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
{   ls -lrt /dir1/dir2/filename*.txt || 
    kill $$ 
} | tail -1 | 
awk '{print $9}' | 
read variable
```

Just `kill` yourself. Sometimes the shell can be a little whiny when I do it, but I find it doesnt even whimper if I do `kill -PIPE $$`.

Or if you would prefer to be specific about return codes and the rest:

```
trap 'echo some error >&2; exit 1' USR1 $and_or_other_signals
{ ls ... || kill -USR1 $$; } |...
```

Regarding the rest.. Maybe another way..?

```
touch ~/"a n\$ew file
in 'my home
directory"
v=$(ls -1rdt ~/* || kill -PIPE $$; echo /)
v=${v%?/*}; v=${v##*/}
printf '<%s>' ~/"$v"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
</home/mikeserv/a n$ew file
in 'my home
directory>
```

That will get you the name of the last modified file in any directory regardless of whatever characters it may contain. I use the `<` `>` to denote the begining and end of the variable and show that it does not contain any trailing white space. And the `echo` bit is to ensure that if there *is* trailing whitespace it persists.

It definitely beats the pipeline and it will still kill a scripted shell if `ls` returns other than 0 - such as when its command-line arguments do not exist.

The same can be done without reversing the sort order, but it is a little trickier, and it requires changing into the target directory to do it at all easily:

```
touch ~/"a n\$ew file
in 'my home
directory"
v=$(cd ~; ls -dtm ./* || kill -PIPE $$)
v=${v#*/}; v=${v%%,?./*}
printf '<%s>' ~/"$v"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
</home/mikeserv/a n$ew file
in 'my home
directory>
```

Another fairly portable method, I think:

```
set /[d]ir1/dir2/filename*.txt
[ -z "${1##/\[*}" ] && exit 1
while [ -n "$2" ] 
do  [ "$1" -nt "$2" ] &&
    set "$@" "$1"
shift; done; v=$1
printf %s\\n "$1" "$v"
```