# exit status and no output

Tags: pipe, output, exit-status

I have a command such that

```
bar > /dev/null
```

and I want to know the exit status of bar. I read some posts [su](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another) about $`{PIPESTATUS[0]}` but this works when one pipes the output via `|` and I can't make it work with `>` instead.

What am I missing?

Comment: From the same question you have referred, you could try `false > /dev/null` and see that only `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` has a value and `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` is null which says the entire `bar > /dev/null` is a single command with no pipe involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>` isn't a command. This means that bar will be the last command executed. You can check for failure with a standard `if` statement:

```
if ! bar > /dev/null; then
    echo "bar command failed"
fi
```

You can also access its return code with `$?` if you are interested in something more than zero or non-zero:

```
bar > /dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 45 ]; then
  echo "bar returned exit code 45"
fi
```

Comment: "> isn't a command. This means that bar will be the last command executed." That is a strange way to describe it. You can have `>/dev/null` before the last command in a pipeline. That can even make sense. The point is that `>` doesn't create a pipeline.