# Parent script continues when child exits with non-zero exit code

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, exit

I have a script that calls another script. When the child script fails, I'd like the parent to fail as well.

In the child script `child_1.sh`, I have something like this:

```
if [ $SOME_BAD_CONDITION ] ; then
  echo "Error message...."
  exit 1
fi
```

In the parent, I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
#...
bash ./child_1.sh
echo "continuing to next step..."
bash ./child_2.sh
bash ./child_3.sh
#...
```

I've set up my environment so that `$SOME_BAD_CONDITION` will always happen, and the script exits as expected and the error message *does* print, but the parent script continues: the message "continuing..." is printed and the next script begins executing.

I thought that having `set -e` would ensure that my parent script fails if any child script exists with a non-zero exit code, but that doesn't seem to be happening. I'm not sure what I got wrong here...

*bash version: 4.2.25*

---

UPDATE:

I tried echoing `$?`:

```
bash ./child_1.sh
echo $?
echo "continuing to next step..."
```

The output looks like this:

```
Error message....
0
continuing to next step...
```

Why doesn't the exit code from the child make it into the parent?

---

ANSWER: The original code snippet was incomplete. The `exit 1` was inside a code block that was piped to tee. My attempt to post a *clean, short* code sample ignored this because I did not realize how significant it was (I'm still fairly new to bash scripting). See my posted answer for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: 4.2.25

Comment: Do you see the problem with that simple script, or only when there's more in that `#...` ellipsis after `set -e`?

Comment: Does `child_1.sh` have a `trap` on `EXIT`? Did you try adding a `echo "$?"` after `bash ./child_1.sh`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: No trap in the child. I tried printing $? and it's always 0.

Comment: The part that you posted looks fine, the issue is therefore in some part that you didn't post. Post some runnable code that would let us reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Gilles: The fault was mine: I over-simplified the code in the example to make it easier to read, and omitted code that I didn't *think* had an effect. I solved my own problem, see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186853/104235 ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Then you need to edit the question to demonstrate the problem. As it is, this question won't help anyone, since people facing the same problem won't be able to tell that it's the same problem.

Comment: You can use `set -eu` in the parent script, and call the child script with `./child_1.sh || exit 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I might have made an error in not posting enough details about the child script - I simplified it for the purpose of this question, but maybe too much. The `exit` statement was buried inside a code block (between `{` and `}`) which was piped to `tee` for logging:

```
{
  #...
  if [ $SOME_BAD_CONDITION ] ; then
    exit 1
  fi
  #...
} | tee -a $LOGFILE
echo "script ended at $date">>$LOGFILE
```

From what I understand, I always got a return code of 0 from this child script because the last `echo` was returning 0. I did some research and discovered [$PIPESTATUS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another/73180#73180). I was able to use this to ensure that when my script tried to exit with exit code 1, it would be passed up to parent script:

```
{
  #...
} | tee -a $LOGFILE
EXIT_CODE=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
echo "script ended at $date">>$LOGFILE
exit $EXIT_CODE
```

Combined with John's suggestion, I have a solution that seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

Since your child processes exit with a proper zero/non-zero exit code convention, and given that you execute them sequentially, I'd say you could just use the `&&` operator:

```
#!/bin/bash

./child_1.sh
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && exit # Exit if non-zero exit code
./child_2.sh
./child_3.sh
./child_4.sh
exit 0
```

Here, `[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && exit` acts like:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then # If: last exit code is non-zero
    exit
fi
```

If you don't have anything to do between the calls, you could even use...

```
#!/bin/bash
./child_1.sh && ./child_2.sh && ./child_3.sh && ./child_4
exit $?
```

The `&&` operator acts like a [short-circuit AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and a zero exit code is pretty much like a `true` boolean value. If at any time in the chain, a script exits with non-zero, the `&&` will fail, and subsequents scripts shouldn't be called.

Comment: I added a debugging statement to print the value of `$?` and it prints `0`. It looks like the exit code from the child script does not get picked up by the parent script.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner There must be a problem with your child script. I tried it myself just now, and my parent script did get the correct exit code back. Make sure your child script exits as you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had a problem in the child script, but it seems I over-simplified the child script in the original post, which is why no one caught it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue stems from how you throw the error in your child script.

From man set "if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in a if statement, part of an && or || list, or if the command's return value is being inverted via !"

Rather than using set -e, use a trap statement and throw an error. (If you need to use the conditional exit.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Yes, you were right, I had a problem in the child script.