# How to capture the exit status of a non-final command in a pipeline?

Tags: zsh, pipe

I want to capture the exit status of a command that takes place somewhere in a pipeline *before* the last position.  For example, if the pipeline is something like

```
command_1 ... | command_2 ... | command_3 ... | ... | command_n
```

...I would like to know how to capture the exit status of `command_1`, or of `command_2`, or of `command_3`, etc.  (Capturing the exit status of `command_n` is trivial, of course.)

Also, in case it matters, this pipeline is occurring inside a zsh shell function.

---

I tried to capture the exit status of `command_1` with something like

```
function_with_pipeline () {

    local command_1_status=-999999  # sentinel value

    { command_1 ...; command_1_status=$? } | command_2 ... | ... | command_n
    ...

}
```

...but after running the pipeline, the value of the `command_1_status` variable was still the sentinel value.

---

FWIW, here's a working example, where the pipeline has only two commands:

```
foo ... | grep ...
```

`foo` is a function defined for the sake of this example, like so:

```
foo () {

    (( $1 & 1 )) && echo "a non-neglible message"
    (( $1 & 2 )) && echo "a negligible message"
    (( $1 & 4 )) && echo "error message" >&2

    return $(( ( $1 & 4 ) >> 2 ))
}
```

The goal is to capture the exit status of the call to `foo` in the pipeline.

The function `function_with_pipeline` implements the (ultimately ineffective) strategy I described above to do this:

```
function_with_pipeline () {

    local foo_status=-999999  # sentinel value

    { foo $1; foo_status=$? } | grep -v "a negligible message"

    printf '%d\ndesired: %d; actual: %d\n\n' $1 $(( ( $1 & 4 ) >> 2 )) $foo_status

}
```

The loop below exercises the `function_with_pipeline` function.  The output shows that the value of the local variable `foo_status` ends up no different from how it started.

```
for i in $(seq 0 7)
do
    function_with_pipeline $i
done
# 0
# desired: 0; actual: -999999
# 
# a non-neglible message
# 1
# desired: 0; actual: -999999
# 
# 2
# desired: 0; actual: -999999
# 
# a non-neglible message
# 3
# desired: 0; actual: -999999
# 
# error message
# 4
# desired: 1; actual: -999999
# 
# error message
# a non-neglible message
# 5
# desired: 1; actual: -999999
# 
# error message
# 6
# desired: 1; actual: -999999
# 
# error message
# a non-neglible message
# 7
# desired: 1; actual: -999999
#
```

I get the same results if I omit the `local` declaration in the definition of `foo_status`.

Comment: I think is there already an answer to this question:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is special array `pipestatus` for that in `zsh`, so try

```
command_1 ... | command_2 ... | command_3
```

and

```
echo $pipestatus[1] $pipestatus[2] $pipestatus[3]
```

and the reason your approach doesn't work is because each pipe runs in separate subshell, with its own variables which are destroyed once you exit the subshell.

---

Just for reference, it is `PIPESTATUS` (with capital letters) in `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

[`mispipe`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) works in any shell. The syntax, (compared to a regular pipe), works like so:

```
mispipe true false ; echo $?  # returns exit code of 1st command `true`
true | false ; echo $?  # returns exit code of 2nd command `false`
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

What to do if there's more than two programs:

```
# this still returns exit code of 1st command `true`
mispipe true 'false | false | false' ; echo $?
```

Output:

```
0
```

Despite the lack of a visible `|`, it still behaves as a pipe should:

```
yes | mispipe head 'wc -c'
```

Output:

```
     20
```