# zsh pipestatus disappears in the following prompt

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, array, exit-status

I am on zsh 5.8 (arm-apple-darwin20.2.0). Unlike the way `PIPESTATUS` in bash is available to read during the next shell prompt, `pipestatus` of pipe in zsh seems to disappear in the following prompt.

```
❯ true | false | true ; echo $pipestatus
0 1 0

❯ true | false | true
❯ echo $pipestatus
0
```

This behavior is unlike that suggested in the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318160/456507), and the zsh document does not mention anything regarding this.

Comment: Maybe something in your prompt or promp commands uses pipes?

Comment: @muru Ok sure, something in zdharma/zinit is doing it... if i add these commands to a script, it prints correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) wrote in a comment, something is using a pipe and thus overwriting `pipestatus`, probably in prompt-related automation. The most likely culprit is a [hook function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) such as `precmd` and `preexec`¹.

Bash saves `$?`, `PIPESTATUS` and a bunch of other things around traps and `PROMPT_COMMAND` ([`save_parser_state`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?h=bash-5.0#n6553)). Zsh saves `$?` in a number of circumstances (in the [source](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/tree/master/Src), look for places that save `lastval`) including around expanding the prompt ([`promptexpand`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/prompt.c#L183)) and running hooks such as `precmd` and `preexec` ([`callhookfunc`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/utils.c#L1512) calls [`doshfunc`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/exec.c#L5660) with `noreturnval=1`), but it never saves `pipestatus`.

¹  <sub>Code in the prompt can also set variables if [`prompt_subst`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST_002c-use-of) is set, but a pipe there would be in a subshell and would not overwrite the original shell's `pipestatus`.</sub>