# how to get the timeout exit code while run a command in background?

Tags: background-process, timeout

I'm writing a shell script to run ping command in background, and in the same time, set a timeout value for ping command, I want to get the exit code if the ping is ended by timeout, I use below:

```
timeout 10s ping -c 5 www.google.com | awk '{print "from local to google |", $0;}' &
exit_status=$?
echo $exit_status
```

but I found that the exit code returned is for "&", the command run in background, not the timeout.

how could I get the timeout exit code?

Comment: Possibly related: [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here.  First, `timeout` takes as argument a **single command**.  So when you write

```
timeout 10s ping -c 5 www.google.com | awk '{print "from local to google |", $0;}'
```

what happens is more or less this:

```
( timeout 10s ping -c 5 www.google.com ) | awk '{print "from local to google |", $0;}'
```

I.e. `timeout` kills `ping`, not the entire pipe, and thus you get back the exit code of the pipe (namely that of `awk`).

To get the exit code of `timeout` you need a subshell.  But since `timeout` takes as argument a single command, you need to write that explicitly:

```
timeout 10 sh -c 'ping ... | awk ...' sh
```

Alternatively you could just time the last command in the pipe (i.e. `awk`):

```
ping ... | timeout 10 awk ...
```

This should work fine for `ping | awk`, but it can be prone to race conditions for other commands.  And if `ping` produces a lot of output you might also may get a SIGPIPE, for killing the listener.

Back to your question, you also want to put all that in background.  To get the exit code of a background command you need to `wait` for it:

```
timeout 10 sh -c 'ping ... | awk ...' sh &
wait $!
echo $?
```

Sadly `bash` doesn't have an asynchronous `wait`, which kind of defeats the purpose of running the commands in background.  You can however run other commands before `wait`.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciate your answer. Actually I wanted to speed up the ping, I'm writing a script to run ping automatically between different hosts and for difference network. so I roughly counted that there gonna have more than 2000 ping, and each ping suppose to send 5 packages. so I was thinking to run the ping in background, so don't have to wait one ping finish then continue another. do you have any idea to speed up? thanks again.

Comment: The bottleneck for `ping`-ing thousands of hosts is likely to be the DNS, not `ping` itself.  This is much better handled by dedicated monitoring programs, but if you must reinvent your own wheel you should probably write a Python script that does asynch DNS lookups, and sends ICMP `echo` packets in several threads.  Doing it in the shell is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: thanks. that's a very good advice. let me start learn the python now......