# Piping 'false' does not give non-zero result code

Tags: bash, pipe, exit-status

I understand these:

```bsh
true;   echo "$?"      # 0
false;  echo "$?"      # 1
true  | echo "$?"      # 0
```

But not this:

```bsh
false | echo "$?"      # 0
```

...Why doesn't it print `1`?

And how could I force a failure in a pipe, and get `1` thereafter?

Comment: Related: [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

Comment: A process in a pipeline can't access the exit status of a previous (or later) process in that same pipeline.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The result of both `true  | echo "$?"` and `false | echo "$?"` is misleading.  The content of `"$?"` will be set *before* piping the command `false` to the command `echo`.

To execute these lines, bash sets up a pipeline of commands.  The pipeline is setup, then the commands started in parallel.  So in your example:

```
true;   echo "$?"      # 0
false;  echo "$?"      # 1
true  | echo "$?"      # 0
```

is the same as:

```
true   
echo "$?"      # 0
false  
echo "$?"      # 1
echo "$?"      # 0
```

`true` is not executed before `echo $?` it is executed at the same time.

Comment: "The content of `$?` will be expanded before piping the command false to the command echo" Wrong. It may happen before or afterwards, depending on the order in which the kernel decides to schedule the two sides of the pipeline.

Comment: @mosvy for me to be wrong on this point, bash would need to perform shell expansions after it calls `fork()` required to setup the pipeline.  That would be surprising but in reality have absolutely no consequence.  The value of `$?` cannot change in the window you describe so it's really moot point.  The logical sequencing is that the value from before the fork is used.  That is, bash's logic will work as if my statement is correct, even if on the CPU the actual timing is different.

Comment: You did not think about it. And yes, `touch foo | echo *` is "non-deterministic" --- yours is an "appeal to consequences". It could be easily proved false with a `fork()` which introduces artificial delays (and that could easily happen on a loaded machine). This answer gives a wrong explanation and should be removed.

Comment: (@mosvy) No. `false | echo "$?"` runs `false` in a _subshell_, and runs `echo "$?"` including expanding `$?` either in another subshell or the parent shell (for bash see shopt lastpipe in the manual or numerous Qs here). In either case the status value used for `$?` is (deterministically) not the value set in the first subshell because values set in that subshell don't affect either another subshell or the parent (although parent bash does subsequently set the status of the subshell(s) in array `PIPESTATUS`). Similarly `cd /elsewhere | echo "$PWD"` will not output `/elsewhere`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 please read what I wrote before commenting. `rm -f foo; touch foo | echo *` is "non-deterministic" (ie it can either echo "foo" or not depending on the load of the machine, etc -- sorry for the obtuse terminology, it wasn't mine ;-)). The explanation from this answer (that in `false | echo $?`, `$?` is always expanded before `false` is run, and that is the reason why `$?` is not 1) is wrong.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 If you're still "certain this never happens" (ie that eg `rm -f *.lol; touch foo.lol | echo *.lol` could ever echo `foo.lol`) then ask a separate Q about it.

Comment: About `touch foo | echo *`: `foo` may well exist before `*` is expanded; just give it enough time, e.g. `touch /home/user/temp/unlikely | echo /[!p]*/*/*/unlikel*` (traversing `/proc` would just add noise). Of course, since parameter expansion is performed before pathname expansion, this doesn't _prove_ that `$?` isn't expanded before the pipeline is set up. Still, I wonder if using the "before/after" argument here was a good choice, given that the definition of `?` ("Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.", from `man bash`) could simply be used instead.

Comment: @mosvy Inline with my earlier statement, the value of `$?` is set before the fork, and subshells cannot modify each other's variables.  Thus the actual timing of expanding `$?` will never alter it's value.  This means directly that your statement "*This answer gives a wrong explanation and should be removed*" is far too strong because you are arguing a [moot point](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/moot--point).  My wording the the answer refers to the [logical timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) not the chronological timing.

Comment: @mosvy: `touch foo | observe_foo` is a different case; changes in the filesystem _are_ visible to the other parts of the pipeline, so _that_ is indeed nondeterminstic. But setting `$?` is NOT visible, and the value read is NOT nondeterministic.

Answer (score 7):

In `false | echo $?`, `$?` is not the exit status of `false` because **`$?` expands to the decimal *exit* status of the most recent *pipeline*** [1], not that of the most recent *command*, *subshell* or *child process*. In `false | echo $?`, `false` is not a pipeline, but just part of one. A simple *complete* command like `false;` is a pipeline, even if does not contain any `|`.

Assuming that `set -o pipefail` is on and the exit status of `false | echo $?` will be that of `false`, `$?` could not be exit the status of the current pipeline either, since the current pipeline hasn't yet exited by the time it echoes it.

It does not matter the order in which the two sides of the pipeline (**which are always run in parallel**) are started or terminated, or whether the `echo $?` is actually run in a child process or subshell.

FWIW, when in a subshell, variables and other parameters are *always* expanded in the context of the current subshell: if `false | echo $?` is implemented by forking separate processes for both sides of the pipeline (which is the case in bash, but not in all shells), `$?` will be expanded in the child process, **after** the `fork()`, and possibly after the left side of the pipeline has exited [2].

> And how could I force a failure in a pipe, and get 1 thereafter?

You use `set -o pipefail`, which is supported in bash, zsh and ksh and should be included in a [future version](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=789#c4103) of the standard. But as explained above, this only affects the value of `$?` *after* the pipeline has exited, not within the pipeline itself.

---

[1] [2.5.2 Special Parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) in SUSv4 standard. Whether a command substitution is considered a pipeline in this context depends on the shell; in most historical and present shells `` :; echo `exit 13` $? `` will print `13`, but in some (like dash, yash or pdksh-derived) it will print `0`.

[2] A simple bash example which may help to understand that is `echo $BASHPID >&2 | echo $BASHPID >&2 | echo $BASHPID >&2`; the `BASHPID` variable is *not* expanded before the 3 child processes are set up and run. Special parameters like `$?` are not special in this regard; they're expanded like any other variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is because both parts of the pipe are run in parallel, so the `false` command has not yet completed (and set `$?`) when the `echo` command already starts to print `$?`, which is still the result of the *previous* command; in your case most likely the last `echo` executed (and that was probably successful).