# Remove files with no data and only header

Tags: rm, delete

I want to remove the files which have only header and no data. I tried the below command and it is working fine, Only issue is it is giving exit status as 1 which should be zero.

```
wc -l /Path/File_*  | while read CNT FN; do [ $CNT -lt 2 ] && [  "$FN" != total ] && rm "$FN"; done
```

I am running this command at Datastage ETL tool and my job is failing.

is there any way to modify the command to get the exit status as 0

Comment: I think this will help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14270/388654

Comment: When `read` can not read more because there is no more data to read, it will fail. Is that what you mean is an issue?

Comment: there are multiple files in the folder, but i want to remove the files which have only header and no data.
For that, I have written to do wc and check if the count is less than 2 remove the file

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to read the whole files (like `wc` does), when you know after the first line that a file has at least 2 lines, I'd do (on a GNU system):

```
LC_ALL=C gawk -v ORS='\0' '
  FNR == 2 {nextfile}
  ENDFILE  {if (FNR < 2) print FILENAME}' /path/File_* |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

That's also more efficient in that it minimises the number of commands being run.

More reliable as it works with arbitrary file names.

As a functional difference with `wc`-based solutions: it would not delete files that contain one delimited line followed by one non-delimited one.

That one only returns a non-zero exit status if a file could not be removed (and was there in the first place).

---

Your problem is that the exit status of that pipe line is the exit status of the right-most command in it (as long as you don't use the `pipefail` option).

The right-most command here is the `while` loop. The exit status of a loop is that of the last command run in the *body* of the loop. In your case, it will be the `[ "$FN" != total ]` command run on the last line of the input, which will be non-zero unless there is only one `/path/File_*` file (in which case `wc` doesn't print the total).

If you changed it to:

```
[ "$CNT" -gt 1 ] || [ "$FN" = total ] || rm -f -- "$FN"
```

You'd only get a non-zero exit status if the last *header* file could not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions return `false` at the end of the loop:

```
# false           # false              = false
[ $CNT -lt 2 ] && [  "$FN" != total ]
```

For example, if `wc -l /path` returns

```
2 total
```

and you run the command

```
                                 # true           # true              = true
wc -l *  | while read CNT FN; do [ $CNT = 2 ] && [  "$FN" = total ] && echo $CNT "$FN"; done
echo $?
0
```

but if you run

```
                                 # false           # true              = false
wc -l *  | while read CNT FN; do [ $CNT = 3 ] && [  "$FN" = total ] && echo $CNT "$FN"; done
echo $?  
1
```

In other words:

```
#false         # false      = false
[ 2 -eq 3 ] && [ bar = foo ]
echo $?
1

#true         # false      = false
[ 3 -eq 3 ] && [ bar = foo ]
echo $?
1

# false         # true      = false
[ 2 -eq 3 ] && [ foo = foo ]
echo $?
1

# true         # true      = true
[ 3 -eq 3 ] && [ foo = foo ]
echo $?
0
```

I would go with a for loop instead of a while loop and a function to return a value if no matches found:

```
foo() {
  ret=1 # no matches found
  for file in *.txt; do # your extension
    [[ $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 1 ]] && echo "rm $file" && ret=0
  done
  return $ret
}
```

Comment: I want to remove the files which have only header and no data in the files

Comment: Thank you, It worked

```
for file in Path/Filename*; do [[ $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 1 ]] && echo "rm $file" ; done
```