# remove empty files and only header :

Tags: bash, rm, mv

In a follow-up question to a [question asked yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583167/remove-files-with-no-data-and-only-header):

I am running the below command in Datastage ETL tool, which executes the script in Linux.

I executed:

```bsh
for file in /Path/filename_*; do [[ $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 1 ]] && rm $file ; done
Reply=0
```

In this case I'm having empty files in the folder:

```bsh
for file in /Path/filename_*; do [[ $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 1 ]] && rm $file ; done
Reply=1
```

I don't have empty files in the folder.

Both are same commands with different reply, my job fails if i get reply code 1

Comment: Your command seems incomplete: `do` is a reserved word to be used in a `for` loop, which is missing in the command you show. Are you sure this is the complete extract from your shell script? If so, I recommend using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to debug your script.

Comment: sorry,  i have updated the command now and updated the question

Comment: So, your second command actually also starts with `for file in`? If so, please edit your post to include that. Also, you don't mention the syntax error any more, and it is unclear now what the problem really is (what does it mean if you say that the command is not successful any more). Please edit to clarify.

Comment: both are same commands, the issue is with the Reply. When i get reply 1, the job fails. The job should run successfully even if there are no empty files

Comment: Same problem as in your other question (last command run in the loop has a non-zero exit status), same solution(s). See my answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62592957

Comment: I have read 3 times, but see no question. What is the question. The only bit that I can workout, is that you have "empty files in the folder" and you "don''t have empty files in the folder". You need to open the box and examine the cat.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid leaving a non-zero status from `[[`, you could use an `if` statement rather than `&&` operator:

```
if [[ $(wc -l <"$file") -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo rm -- "$file"
fi
```

---

Instead of counting all lines, you may only need to read up to the second line:

```
for file in /Path/filename_*; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  {
    read _
    read _ || echo rm -- "$file"
  } <"$file"
done
```

If the second `read` fails, then there is no second line (according to POSIX).

Comment: nice. what exactly does `read _`

Comment: @alecxs `_` is just a var name ([POSIX `read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) requires an arg). Not required in bash/zsh/ksh.