# Get exit status of the first command in a pipe in the second the command

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, exit-status, subshell

My question is similar to [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another), but I want to get the exit status of the second command in the pipe *within* the pipe.

Here's an example -

```
false | echo $?
```

returns `0` rather than the intended `1`

`PIPESTATUS` gives the previous error code out

```
false | echo $PIPESTATUS
```

returns `0` the first time and then `1`, giving the result after the operation itself. My intent with this is to make a function like this:

```
debug() {
  # Eventually will be formatted as JSON
  echo "$(cat) was the result and the error code was $?"
}

(
  echo "Foo"
  false # To simulate an error
) | debug # debug should return "Foo was the result and the error code was 1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that as such, because the two halves of a pipe execute **simultaneously**, so the right-side has no way to know whether the left side was successful or not.  To do what you want, you have to run the left-side command first, and wait for it to exit.  Then you can present the output from the command and the exit code.

You may find that this snippet is more amenable to your purposes:

```
myfunc() {
  echo foo
  read
}

out="$(myfunc)"
rc=$?
printf '%s was the result and the error code was %d\n' "$out" $rc

$ yes | ./test.sh 
foo was the result and the error code was 0
$ ./test.sh < /dev/null
foo was the result and the error code was 1
```

Comment: Technically, you could start two processes connected with a pipe at the same time, and then have the second eventually get the exit status of the first through some means. Would be awkward to do in the shell in the least, and the reading side of the pipe would have to buffer all input anyway before proceeding past the point where it needs the exit status to decide what to do. It does rather circumvent the point of a pipeline, though.

Comment: Here, where the eventual output starts with the output of the LHS anyway, one could just run `whatever; printf ' was the result and the error code was %d\n' "$?"`. But if they want to reformat the output as JSON or something, they'll have to buffer.  A minor point to note is that command substitution eats trailing newlines, so if you want to avoid that, just using a temporary file might be a thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

[Jim's Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743957/528987) is definitely the correct one. However, in my specific use case, I found that the `trap` command offered me the clean syntax of a pipe while still catching errors.

I ended up going with this:

```
set -E

trap 'catch $? $LINENO' ERR

catch() {
    echo "{ \"type\": \"error\", \"error\": \"$1\", \"line\": \"$2\" }"
    exit $1
}

debug() {
  # Eventually will be formatted as JSON
  echo "$(cat) was the result"
}

(
  echo "Foo"
  # Simulate an error
  false
  echo "This should not be run!"
) | debug
```

which outputs:

```
Foo
{ "type": "error", "error": "1", "line": "18" } was the result
```

As you can see, `echo "This should not be run!"` is never executed!

In the end, with the JSON formatted to replace newlines with `\n`, you get this:

```
{ "content": "Foo\n{ "error": "1", "line": "18" }" }
```

It needs a bit of post-processing, specifically to fix the nested quotes and/or to seperate the `stdin` input from the `trap` output.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I don't know what causes the second error, and I'm not sure whether it affects your use case, but notice that without the `| debug` at the end, your script generates two errors, at line 18 and line 20.  With the `| debug` added, only the first error is reported.