# What does ` in Linux means?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

What does ` in Linux means? The sign with tilde on keypad. Does it evaluates the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've answered your own question. Yes, basically it evaluates what's in between the backticks and then whatever happens after that happens. I'd write an explanation myself but there seems to be plenty of others who have already tried and been pretty successful with it.

[Understanding backtick (`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick)