# How do I convert a date to milliseconds since Unix epoch in bash?

Tags: bash, timestamps

I've got a date in format:

```
22-Sep-2014 10:32:35
```

I need a 13-digit timestamp, but when I convert this way

```
time=$(date -d "$DATE" '+%s')
```

I get a 10-digit number

When I try

```
tt=$(date -d "$DATE");
time=$($tt +'%s * 1000 + %-N / 1000000')
```

I get

```
line 22: Mon: command not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get milliseconds since Unix epoch?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69322/how-to-get-milliseconds-since-unix-epoch)

Comment: Linked question is in regards to the current time, as of when the command was run, not converting an existing time.

Answer (score 14):

Your second attempt was close, just need to tell the `date` command to add milliseconds to the end. You can do this with the `%N` formatter. `%N` expands to nanoseconds, and then you can just truncate that by using `%3N`.
Note however that your example input time does not have any milliseconds on it, so you could just add `.000` to the end.
Assuming this is not what you want, here's an example that provides millisecond accuracy:

```
$ DATE="22-Sep-2014 10:32:35.012"
$ date -d "$DATE" +'%s.%3N'
1411396355.012
```

Comment: How can I interpret the number after the dot, here 012? Is it a decimal number? How can I convert the current date to ms? With `DATE=$(date)`?

Comment: just a note that `%N` is not available on the BSDs `date`