# How do I substract 5 minutes from a Unix timestamp?

Tags: bash, timestamps

I have a date in milliseconds since Unix epoch format, how do I substract 5 minutes from it?

Answer (score 10):

Supposing your timestamp is in a variable `timestamp`, and in milliseconds since the epoch:

```
fiveminutesbefore=$((timestamp - 5 * 60 * 1000))
```

This uses [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to subtract 5 lots of 60 (seconds in a minute) lots of 1000 (milliseconds in a second) from your value `timestamp`, giving a time five minutes earlier as you would expect.

Comment: My timestamp is actually passed as an argument into my bash script, and it won't do ss=$(($1-5*60*1000))...How can I convert it before substracting?

Comment: Are you sure this is Bash? `ss=$(($1-5*60*1000))` is valid and working Bash. You can save it in a named variable first if you want: `timestamp=$1`, but it shouldn't make any difference. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: There was an error, the argument had an incorrect format! Thanks for your anser)

Answer (score 4):

5 minutes of 60 seconds of 1000 milliseconds each gives 300000.

You can subtract this from a variable that containts current date in milliseconds using `$(( ))`:

```
dd=$(($(date +'%s * 1000 + %-N / 1000000')))
ddmin5=$(($dd - 300000))
echo $ddmin5
```

The milliseconds calculation comes from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69324/33055)

Comment: The nice thing about the "seconds since epoch" format is that for a computation like this, there is no need to consider time zones or corner cases for daylight savings or leap seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many ways:

```
fiveminutesbefore=$[$timestamp - 5 * 60 * 1000]
```

or

```
fiveminutesbefore=`echo "$timestamp - 5 * 60 * 1000" | bc -l`
```

or

```
fiveminutesbefore=`echo "$timestamp" | python -c 'import sys; t=sys.stdin.read(); print int(t) - 5 * 60 * 1000'`
```

etc...

Comment: Hello and welcome to ul.sx! Please be specific and ensure your answers are always complete, including stating you answer's idea before providing code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the strftime() function and the FIELDWIDTHS variable.

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='10 3' '{ print strftime("%s" $2, $1-5*60) }' <<<'1623660409789'
1623660109789
```

Answer (score -3):

print solaris sun os minus 10min

```
dt="$(date +%H:"$(( `date +%M`-10))":%S)"
```

Comment: Mind adding some description?

Comment: it will give time as 6:-10:00 if you run at 6:00. when it should give 5:50:00