# Rsync bash script error (sending: command not found)

Tags: shell-script, rsync

I have a backup script for my server that mostly works. Only the the rsync commands throw an error in the log I can't find a solution to.

Here's **part** of my script (I removed the working stuff):

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
BKROOT="/home/roots/backups"
BKDIR="/home/roots/backups/$TIMESTAMP"

LOG="$BKROOT/backup_$TIMESTAMP.log"

function log () 
{
    now=$(date +"%T")
    echo -e "$now: $1"
}

echo -e "Starting backup..."

if [ ! -d "$BKDIR" ]; then
        echo -e "Creating Backup directory $BKDIR..."
        mkdir -p $BKDIR
        mkdir -p $BKDIR/games
        mkdir -p $BKDIR/games/minecraft
fi

# Redirect all output to log
exec >> $LOG 
exec 2>&1

log "Saving Minecraft..."
`/usr/bin/rsync -av /var/games/minecraft $BKDIR/games/minecraft --exclude 'plugins/dynmap/web'`
log

# Sleeping 10 seconds to allow file access
sleep 10

# Compressing backup
log "Compressing backup to $BKROOT/backup_$TIMESTAMP.tar.gz..."
`/bin/tar czvfP $BKROOT/backup_$TIMESTAMP.tar.gz "$BKDIR"`
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    log "Error during compression"
else 
    log "Compression OK"
fi

# Uploading backup to Backup storage
log "Uploading backup and log to Backup storage..."
`/usr/bin/scp $BKROOT/backup_$TIMESTAMP.tar.gz user@server.domain:/`
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    log "Error during upload of backup"
else 
    log "Uploading of backup OK"
fi
`scp $LOG user@server.domain:/`
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    log "Error during upload of backup log"
else 
    log "Uploading of backup log OK"
fi
log

TIMEEND=`date "+%m/%d/%Y @ %H:%M"`

# Logging free space on backup location
echo 'df -h' | sftp user@server.domain.de

# Sending mail
`echo "Done" | mutt -s "Backup completed on $TIMEEND" -i $LOG user@domain.com`

# Removing backup folder
echo -e "Removing temporary folder"
log "Removing temporary folder..."
`rm $BKDIR -rf`
```

The script is running as root via cronjob. Everything is working fine, except the rsync commands. Every single one of them is writing the following error into the logfile:

> 20:19:38: Saving Minecraft...
>   /home/roots/scripts/backup.sh: line 126: sending: command not found
>   20:21:07: 
>   20:21:40: Backup of www-data files
>   /home/roots/scripts/backup.sh: line 141: sending: command not found
>   /home/roots/scripts/backup.sh: line 142: sending: command not found
>   20:22:58: 
>   20:23:03: Copying FHEM backups
>   /home/roots/scripts/backup.sh: line 157: sending: command not found

All 4 rsync commands have the exact same parameters except for the source and destination paths.

The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

Anyone got an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Your shell script is only 71 lines long, while the errors are from lines well above that. Is `rsync` really at `/usr/bin/rsync` ? (test this with `which rsync` in a shell)

Comment: The actual script is a lot longer - I just cut out all the working parts to keep it cleaner. Yes, rsync is at /usr/bin/rsync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lines like this:

```
`/usr/bin/rsync -av /var/games/minecraft $BKDIR/games/minecraft --exclude 'plugins/dynmap/web'`
```

The backticks mean to [execute the output of the command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands) in between them. So the `rsync` command runs, creates some output, and the shell *tries to execute that output*. Simply remove the backticks and you'll be okay:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av /var/games/minecraft $BKDIR/games/minecraft --exclude 'plugins/dynmap/web'
```

Comment: You were right. Thank you very much for the explaination!