# Why did Debian use the typewriter apostrophe (') instead of the closed curve quote (’)

Tags: debian, quoting, history

I have been using Debian for quite a few years. Every now and then, when I write or read something I find it confusing what an author meant by it. I had a look at the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe), as well as this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85303/where-does-this-convention-for-quotation-marks-come-from/85319) . I found it pretty interesting that the Unicode consotrium puts it as being pretty [context-dependant](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch06.pdf) where in the 33 paqes of chapter 6 it says it depends on the context. But this doesn't tell the story as to why (') was used.

Another query is do all linux distributions do use 'typewriter apostrophe' as been shared on wikipedia rather than the classical closed quotation marks which is/was shared in handwriting.

Comment: This really isn't on-topic.  As indicated on the very _closed as off-topic_ question that you point to, these are typographical questions that are _not_ specific to Unix & Linux.  It is really reaching to ask about Debian as if there were something specific to Debian here.  It reads as bizarrely as asking why Debian spells the word "color" as it does, and asking whether other Linux distributions do too.  This is not Unix & Linux stuff, and is based upon a faulty premise and a connection that does not exist.

Comment: See also [Is the tick or acute accent character (´) used for anything in Linux shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479352/86440).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Unix dates back to times where terminals where teletypes and had a rather limited character set, which eventually becomes standardized as ASCII. And ASCII only has straight single quote and double quote.