# delete everything before specific position in a text file

Tags: shell-script

I have file "report.csv" . This report is generated based on few parameters
 which can range from 1-10. So the report.csv has all the parameters printed in 
it first and then , the main header and the data. Now I need to process 
this file with the header and data and exclude all the parameters. The file looks like this:

```
para_1: abc
para_2: def
para_3: ghi
.
.
.
para_n: xyz

Customer_Name, Customer_Number, .....
Jon Doe,19923
Adam Plak,19985
.
.
.
```

I used below command to get the position of the Column header

This gives me the position

```
grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1
```

(let's say) `13`. Then I use this command to copy to another file and use the new file

```
sed '1,13d' report.csv >> report_test.csv
```

however i need to make it dynamic , like

```
$var1 = grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1
$var2 = d
sed '1,$var1$var2' report.csv >> report_test.csv
```

can you experts please help achieve this in Shell Script?

Comment: Actually, why can't you do everything in `sed` like `sed '1,/Customer_Name/' report.csv >> report_test.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var1=`grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1`
var2='d'
sed "1,${var1}${var2}"  report.csv  >> report_test.csv
```

OR

```
var1=$(grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1)
var2='d'
sed "1,${var1}${var2}"  report.csv  >> report_test.csv
```

**Explanation**

What we needed here is **command substitution**

The command substitution can be done in two ways one is using

- **$(…)**
- **`…`**

The purpose of command substitution is to evaluate the command which is placed inside the backtick and provide its result as an argument to the actual command.

**Difference between the two command substitution methods**

The old-style backquotes ` `  treat backslashes and nesting a bit different. The new-style $() interprets everything in between ( ) as a command. The new-style $() applies to all POSIX-conformant shells.

These are good reads to understand command substitution better:

- [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-)   between-stuff-and-stuff
- [What does ` (backquote/backtick) mean in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands)

Comment: when i Do this 
var1=$(grep -n "Customer Invoice Delivery" b | cut -d : -f1)

i get below error
cm01-dev:@/tmp>sh test_sh.sh
test_sh.sh: syntax error at line 1: `var1=$' unexpected

content of test_sh.sh is


var1=$(grep -n "Customer_Name" b | cut -d : -f1)
echo $var1
var2='d'
echo $var2
sed "1,${var1}${var2}"  report.csv  >> report_test.csv

Comment: Can you try again, in my case file name was `b` , I have edited back my answer with  your file name `report.csv` ?
So it should be `var1=$(grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1)`

Comment: it still gives the same error

test_sh.sh: syntax error at line 2: `var1=$' unexpected

Comment: problem is assignment of the value of 


grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1

in variable var1

Comment: you can try var1=\`grep -n "Customer_Name" report.csv | cut -d : -f1\`
Use `\`` sign to enclose the statement

Comment: thanks Arushix , this time it worked.
but if possible can you please explain why it worked this time ?

Comment: I have added an explanation in the answer