# Find if an IP from a list is present in another list of ip

Tags: ip, search

i ve been reading lots of example here and i didn t find a solution to my problem.
i have been given a list of 1200 IP one per line, and i need to verify if we have a trace of any of these ip in a log fine.
so i have file ip.txt and log.txt, witch contain also one ip per line.

thxx for your help

Comment: `grep -Fx -f ip.txt log.txt`

Comment: you should make that an answer.

Comment: thxx a lot Jetchisel, but that doesn t work i ve added one of the ip from ip.txt in log.txt to see if it s find it, and it doesn t

grep -Fx -f ip.txt log.txt

nocomp@P0wnBox:/media/nocomp/2CFD-E610/ip$ any idea why? thx for your time

Comment: You said you have two files, `ip.txt` and `log.txt` now if you have more to parse/do please update your question and post it. Show some sample input of both files and the desired output, and please post something what have you tried to do.

Comment: yes i have two file, i ve added one ip frim ip.txt in log.txt in order to see if the script find it, but it doesn t when i run grep -Fx -f ip.txt log.txt

Comment: Try replacing the `x` with `w` option from grep and see if it helps.

Comment: There are almost certainly more elegant solutions (and you may need to adjust it to your data) but something along these lines may work: `IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat ip.txt); do cat log.txt | grep -q $i && echo $i; done`

Comment: nop, same results :/

Comment: hi mark, it didn t worked either:nocomp@P0wnBox:/media/nocomp/2CFD-E610/ip$ IFS=$'\n'; for i in cat anssi.txt; do cat palo.txt | grep -q $i && echo $i; done
nocomp@P0wnBox:/media/nocomp/2CFD-E610/ip$

Comment: @nocomp - i've adjusted my comment as the backticks (old style command substition) were not displayed correctly (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands). Try the edited post

Comment: @nocomp, then you need to post both sample of the files in question.

Comment: In case the demand gets more complex: checking if an IP is inside a list of  networks (ranges of IPs), there's a dedicated tool: [`grepcidr`](https://manpages.debian.org/grepcidr/grepcidr.1)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing

```
comm -12 <(sort ip.txt) <(sort log.txt)
```