# Is listing files with ls dangerous as stated on gnu.org documentation?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, security

Is listing files with ls dangerous?

If I run just ls command in a directory with unknown files, can something bad happen?

Can you show me examples how running ls command is dangerous as stated in this phrase from gnu.org documentation:

> Too many naive users are running 'ls' in directories from
> untrustworthy sources.

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/quotes.html

Comment: it can help hacker to identify targets feven from only a filename sometimes, as first  example but it can olso permit to identify other thigs I guess. as the first example I have in mind

Comment: The actual prohibitions should be 1) Don't have `.` in your `$PATH` (`./ls` could be anything); and 2) Output of `ls` is inconsistent, and cannot be parsed reliably, for use in pipelines, use `stat` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: The context of those FAQ answers is not invoking `ls` but rather copy+paste of the `ls` output that's displayed on a terminal window, or piping the `ls` output to other programs to parse the contents.

Answer (score 1):

The danger is not in solely running `ls`. The danger is in typing or pasting its output. E.g. from an untrustworthy source you can get a file named `&date;`. If you run some traditional `ls` (or GNU `ls -N`) then you will see

```
&date;
```

If you don't know what `&` and `;` do in the shell then it will be easy for you to run one of these:

```
nano &date;
file &date;
rm &date;
cp &date; whatever
```

Any of these commands immediately runs `date`. `date` is not a harmful command, I deliberately chose a safe example. But what if the file is literally named `` funny story about `rm …`.txt ``? Oh boy, let's see it! You may even be aware that a name with spaces requires quoting or escaping, there is a chance you choose double-quotes; and then:

```
less "funny story about `rm …`.txt"
```

In fact this exact command is almost always safe (it's safe, unless you have a file named `…` you want to keep), but imagine this scenario with `-rf ~` in place of `…`. [The inside of the backticks will be executed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27428/108618) regardless if unquoted or double-quoted. To safely examine the file you should e.g. single-quote the name:

```
less 'funny story about `rm …`.txt'
```

The above command will not run `rm`.

The documentation you linked to is about the feature of GNU `ls` designed to protect naive users from this kind of mishaps. It explicitly states one of the reasons to change the default output is

> Easier and safer cutting and pasting of filenames from/to the terminal

In the case of our example filenames GNU `ls` will show you `'&date;'` or `` 'funny story about `rm …`.txt' ``. The point is if you type or paste exactly this after a command like `file` or `less` then you will quote right; maybe unwittingly, but right; even if you know nothing about how your shell interprets `&` or backticks.

The feature is more sophisticated than "single-quote everything". Filenames themselves may contain single-quotes, so embracing mindlessly with single-quotes does not always work. In general GNU `ls` may use backslashes, single-quotes, double-quotes, even [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) to show you filenames in safe forms you can paste*.

---

<sup>* Not all shells understand ANSI-C quoting, although if you're using GNU `ls` then you're probably using a modern shell that does understand it (e.g. GNU `bash`). Besides, it's not about creating snippets that in all circumstances work as expected when pasted; it's about avoiding snippets that work not as expected (or maybe rather "that work as expected by their rogue authors").</sup>