# How can I pipe a path to pushd?

Tags: shell, pipe, parameter, stdin

This seems like it should be easy enough to do, but I'm clearly not understanding something fundamental about piping output back and forth.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
bundle show some-gem-name | pushd
```

Where the result puts me in the path of the gem name with popd functionality supported to get back where I was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pushd expects the directory as a command line argument, not as standard input so you cannot pipe the directory to it.  Try

```
pushd "`bundle show some-gem-name`"
```

instead.

Comment: Alternative: `pushd "$(bundle show some-gem-name)"` - works identical, but could be easier to type depending on the keyboard layout. `$(...)` can be used nested.

Comment: @jofel The difference is more than that. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/9382

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Actually in this case there is no difference. backticks and `$(…)` only differ when there are backslashes or backticks inside.

Comment: @Gilles OK, thanks for pointing that out.  To make it clear: I referred to jofel's comment on ease of typing - which shouldn't be seen as the only difference **in general** (when someone reads this slightly out of context).