# How can I convert a pdf file from gray-scale to black-white?

Tags: command-line, pdf

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. How can I convert a pdf file from gray-scale to black-white? The gray-scale pdf file comes from scanning with gray-scale option, and the black-white scale pdf is required by OCR.

---

Update:

Following Marco's reply, [the B-W pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/mono.pdf) isn't good and the original file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/all.pdf).

Comment: try `scantailor`

Comment: `scantailor` has tons of other useful features when it comes to preparing scans for OCR, and that's the only reason why I suggested it (as a comment, not an answer)

Comment: You can open, and export, (at least some).pdf's in libreoffice (and hence I would guess most modern word processors).  Don't know if that will make your desired change possible or easy tho.

Comment: There's also `pdfimages` (poppler) to extract scanned images from its PDF container. May be more efficient to handle them with ImageMagick in the first place.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9868/convert-an-image-from-grayscale-to-binary

Answer (score 11):

1) Use [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to convert the PDF to a monochrome PostScript file using the *psmono* device:

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=psmono -o mono.ps input.pdf
```

2) Then convert the monochrome PostScript back to PDF:

```
ps2pdf mono.ps
```

*EDIT:* The `psmono` device creates a 1-bit half-tone image which is apparently not what you want. I couldn't find a way to specify a threshold using ghostscript, so I resorted to imagemagick. `convert` internally uses ghostscript to convert the PDF. It then applies the threshold filtering to produce a 1-bit image and uses ghostscript again to create a PDF. Since `convert` uses a resolution of 75DPI by default, which might not match your actual resolution, you can provide the `density` argument. And experiment with the `threshold` setting. The optimal values highly depend on the input file.

```
convert -density 150 -threshold 50% input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem of running the first command: the original gray-scale pdf is about 25MB, and the running hasn't finished yet after 15min, and the output file mono.ps is already 150MB and still increasing. I am worrying about that. Are there other ways, for example, print to B-W pdf file?

Comment: @Tim That's not uncommon. PostScript files are uncompressed, the resulting PDF will be smaller.

Comment: Thanks. It took about 20mins. [The B-W pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/mono.pdf) isn't good. and the original file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/all.pdf)

Comment: @Tim horrible quality, not suited for OCR no matter what you do.

Comment: I have got excellent result with `convert -density 300 -threshold 75% input.pdf output.pdf`. Range between 50%-75% removes all gray noise and makes copy well printable. In my case I am working with scanned colorful documents which I needs to print sometimes. It may not work good when you have non-image based PDF, you will get huge output file size.

Answer (score 5):

Best way I found out there, without quality loss, removes shadows, noise, text from the next page bleeding through etc:

1. First convert pdf to individual images

   `pdfimages combined_ocr.pdf page`
2. Second remove shadows, noise, text from the next page bleeding through (credits [to this blog](https://tinyapps.org/blog/nix/201802020700_remove_all_color_but_black.html) )

   `ls ./p*.ppm | xargs -L1 -I {} convert {}  -quality 100 -density 300 -fill white -fuzz 80% +opaque "#000000" {}.jpg`

this could be added as either extra-step or instead of the command above to actually get only two colors:

```
ls ./p*.ppm | xargs -L1 -I {} convert {} +dither -colors 2 -type bilevel -density 300 -fill white -fuzz 40% +opaque "#000000" -density 300 {}.jpg
```

50-60% percent `fuzz` is less aggressive and gets more readable results:

```
ls ./p*.ppm | xargs -L1 -I {} convert {} +dither -colors 2 -type bilevel -density 300 -fill white -fuzz 40% +opaque "#000000" -density 300 {}.jpg
```

3. This to make a pdf file out of every jpg image without loss of either resolution or quality:

   `ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf`
4. This to concatenate the pdfpages into one:

   `pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf`
5. And last I add an OCRed text layer that doesn't change the quality of the scan in the pdfs so they can be searchable:

   `pypdfocr combined.pdf`

Comment: I have my `ls` aliased to `ls -FGlAhp`, so to make steps 2 and 3 work, I replaced `ls` with `command ls`. (It took me a moment to figure this out, so I mention it here in case others had a similar issue.)

Comment: @AlexRoberts good to know if someone aliased their `ls` command which is probably not that often

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if it comes from a scan, the only reasonable way is to use pdfimages and convert the underlying graphics. I used this script to convert it:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Syntax: $0 <input.pdf> <output.pdf>"
    exit 1
fi

pdfimages "$1" scan
for a in scan*.ppm; do 
   convert -white-threshold 85% -monochrome $a `basename $a .ppm`.tiff
done
tiffcp scan*.tiff output.tiff
tiff2pdf output.tiff -o "$2" -p A4 -F
rm scan*.ppm scan*.tiff output.tiff
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had some scanned color pdfs and grayscale pdfs that I wanted to convert to bw. I tried using `gs` with the [code listed here](https://superuser.com/a/164857), and image quality is good with pdf text still there. However, that gs code only converts to grayscale (as asked in the question) and still has large file size. `convert` yields very poor results when used directly.

I wanted bw pdfs with good image quality and small file size. My solution uses `gs` to extract grayscale bmp files from the pdf, `convert` to threshold those bmps to bw and save them as tiff files, and then [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf) to compress the tiff images and merge them all into one pdf.

I tried going directly to tiff from the pdf but the quality is not the same so I save each page to bmp. For a one page pdf file, `convert` does a great job from bmp to pdf. Example:

```
gs -sDEVICE=bmpgray -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r300x300 \
   -sOutputFile=./pdf_image.bmp ./input.pdf

convert ./pdf_image.bmp -threshold 40% -compress zip ./bw_out.pdf
```

For multiple pages, `gs` can merge multiple pdf files into one, but `img2pdf` yields smaller file size than gs. The tiff files must be uncompressed as input to img2pdf. Keep in mind for large numbers of pages, the intermediate bmp and tiff files tend to be large in size. `pdftk` or `joinpdf` would be better if they can merge compressed pdf files from `convert`.

I imagine there is a more elegant solution. However, my method produces results with very good image quality and much smaller file size. To get text back in the bw pdf, run OCR again.

My shell script uses gs, convert, and img2pdf. Change the parameters (# of pages, scan dpi, threshold %, etc) listed in the beginning as needed, and run `chmod +x ./pdf2bw.sh` . Here is the full script (pdf2bw.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

num_pages=12
dpi_res=300
input_pdf_name=color_or_grayscale.pdf
bw_threshold=40%
output_pdf_name=out_bw.pdf
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gs -sDEVICE=bmpgray -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -r$dpi_res \
   -sOutputFile=./%d.bmp ./$input_pdf_name
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
for file_num in `seq 1 $num_pages`
do
  convert ./$file_num.bmp -threshold $bw_threshold \
          ./$file_num.tif
done
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
input_files=""

for file_num in `seq 1 $num_pages`
do
  input_files+="./$file_num.tif "
done

img2pdf -o ./$output_pdf_name --dpi $dpi_res $input_files
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# clean up bmp and tif files used in conversion

for file_num in `seq 1 $num_pages`
do
  rm ./$file_num.bmp
  rm ./$file_num.tif
done
```

Comment: this works, but is slow. [gs -sOutputFile=output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBlackText -dBlackVector -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH input.pdf](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474303/877276) works too, but is much faster

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to OccamsRazor for his script, which does a great job of converting both color and grayscale PDFs into a compact and legible monochrome version.  This is really a comment on OccamsRazor's post, but I don't have enough points to comment.

The script will fail on
    `img2pdf -o ./$output_pdf_name --dpi $dpi_res $input_files`
as `--dpi` is no longer an accepted argument for img2pdf.  Instead, it gets the resolution from the input file, so you can just leave it out.

Here's my version of the script.  I didn't want to edit the script for every file, so I pass in the number of pages and input file name when I run it.  I have the output name set to `00input_name` and resolution set to 200 dpi, which works for my workflow, but you may wish to change it, or turn them into `$3` and `$4` and pass them in.

To run, use `./pdf2bw.sh <number_of_pages> <input_name>`, e.g., `./pdf2bw.sh 55 input.pdf`.

```
#!/bin/bash

num_pages=$1
input_pdf_name=$2
output_pdf_name="00$2"
bw_threshold=40%
dpi_res=200
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gs -sDEVICE=bmpgray -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -r$dpi_res \
   -sOutputFile=./%d.bmp ./$input_pdf_name
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
for file_num in `seq 1 $num_pages`
do
  convert ./$file_num.bmp -threshold $bw_threshold \
          ./$file_num.tif
done
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
input_files=""

for file_num in `seq 1 $num_pages`
do
  input_files+="./$file_num.tif "
done

img2pdf -o ./$output_pdf_name $input_files
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# clean up bmp and tif files used in conversion

for file_num in `seq 1 $num_pages`
do
  rm ./$file_num.bmp
  rm ./$file_num.tif
done
```

Comment: You should quote your shell variables; especially the ones that come from arguments or other user input: e.g., `"./$input_pdf_name"` and even ``seq 1 "$num_pages"``. Also, you might want to change `\`…\`` to `$(…)` — see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838), and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119).

Comment: This is OccamsRazor's script except for the changes I noted. I'm no shell programmer, so I didn't want to mess with something that worked.  But if anyone wants to clean this up, you have my thanks.