# Convert pdf font colors to monochrome black

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

What I want to do is convert a pdf file that has colorful fonts to one that all it's fonts' colors are black.

This is **not** [a duplicate of this question here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93959/how-to-convert-a-color-pdf-to-black-white) I don't want greyscale fonts I want them to be only black. `gs` with `psmono` device is not an option since it was removed in later ghostscript releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
convert -monochrome in.pdf out.pdf
```

Option 2:

You can still download Ghostscript 9.07

https://ghostscript.com/Ghostscript_9.07.html

Compile it from source and `make install` the result.

In v9.07 the `psmono` output device still works.
If you want to use the new v9.2+ version also, do not install the compiled v9.07 version but use it directly.

e.g.

```
./gs907 -sDEVICE=psmono -o out.ps -f in.pdf
```

Note:
the PSMono device will flatten your file and make the content text not selectable.

Comment: In October 2018 you can get GS 9.07 source from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files/GPL%20Ghostscript/

Comment: Using `psmono` I also get *terrible* (pixely) results and in fact a greyscale pdf or ps file "converted" this way still contains greyscale text (not black)... (Unfortunately, [my own/adapted solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/727906/86044) stopped working for me on a new machine.)