# What's the difference of get command output using`command`and $(command) in Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the difference in collect a command output in Shell script using `command` and $(command)? For example:

```
# IP1=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -e "inet " | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}')
# IP2=`ifconfig eth0 | grep -e "inet " | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
# echo $IP1 $IP2
> 192.241.145.112 192.241.145.112
```

Comment: Sidenote: your triple pipe seems a bit useless, why no `|awk -F: '/inet/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that backticks don't nest: You cannot embed one backticked command inside another. (Actually you can, but you need to backslash-escape them, and it gets hairier from there on.) That was, I believe, the main motivation for coming up with the newer syntax `$(command)`.

The `$(command)` syntax also provides a convenient shortcut for interpolating the contents of a file: `$(<filename)` is equivalent to `$(cat filename)`.

Another difference: `$()` is not supported by some common shells.

Comment: You can nest backticks with any (Bourne syntax) shell, not just bash. $( ) is not a bash extension, it is a standard syntax supported by all POSIX conforming shells and some non conforming ones.

Comment: @jlliagre, thanks for the correction. Are you sure about the POSIX part? I checked before posting, and my `tcsh` does not support it. Perhaps it's not POSIX compliant (I haven't checked), but this means that you don't have to go exotic or ancient to run into problems.

Comment: I'm more than sure about the POSIX part. It's no surprise `tcsh` doen't support it. `tcsh` is absolutely not a bourne compatible shell but a `csh` one and has zero POSIX conformance.

Comment: I see, thanks. I didn't know that the `csh` line is outside the POSIX pale.

Answer (score 1):

The command substitution `$( )` syntax was introduced around 25 years ago by `ksh` to overcome the limitations of the original " `command` " one, especially the complex way to achieve command nesting.

It was included by the POSIX shell standard and by other shells aiming standard conformance like `bash`.

The old syntax was supported in `ksh88` only to provide compatibility with legacy scripts. There was a hope for it become obsolete but unfortunately, the "new" syntax is still not enough advertised or taught and the legacy syntax is still too much used and popular.