# Simultaneously check for empty output and successful exit status

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution, error-handling, exit-status

I'd like to write the following test in an installer script<sup>1</sup>:

```
if [ -n "`/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`" ]; then
    install_dual_boot
else
    install_linux_only
fi
```

However, it's also possible that `30_os-prober` produces no output because it somehow failed to complete.  If `30_os-prober` fails with a non-zero exit status, it would be safer to assume the a dual-boot situation.

How can I check that `30_os-prober` produced no output *successfully*?

Basically, I would like to obtain an effect similar to…

```
if [ -n "`/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`" ]; then
    # Do stuff for a dual-boot machine
    install_dual_boot
elif ! /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober >/dev/null; then
    # OS probe failed; assume dual boot out of abundance of caution
    install_dual_boot
else
    install_linux_only
fi
```

… but without running the same command twice.

---

<sup>1</sup> Background information: `30_os-prober` comes with [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/), and the script I am writing is part of my custom configuration for [FAI](http://fai-project.org/).

Comment: You don't have to run the command inside the `[]`'s of an `if` statement...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: You need the exit status and the output.  You can't get both if you constrain yourself to running the command inside `[]`'s.  As ferada's answer shows....

Comment: Your question is inconsistent: the first code block says `if [ -z … ] then install_dual_boot` but the second one says `if [ -n … ] then install_dual_boot`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, while they are functionally equivalent,
`$(…)` is widely considered to be clearer than `` `…` `` —
see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/23408), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838/23408), and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119/23408).  Secondly,
you don’t need to use `$?` to check whether a command succeeded or failed. 
My attention was recently drawn to [Section 2.9.1, **Simple Commands**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)
of [The Open Group Base Specifications for Shell & Utilities (Issue 7)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html):

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.
>
> When a given simple command is required to be executed …
>                             ⋮                                                                                *(blah, blah, blah …)*
>
> If there is a command name, execution shall continue as described
>   in [Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01).  If there is no command name,
>   but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete
>   with the exit status of the last command substitution performed.  …

For example,

- the exit status of the command

  ```
  ls -ld "module_$(uname).c"
  ```

  is the exit status from the `ls`, but
- the exit status of the command

  ```
  myfile="module_$(uname).c"
  ```

  is the exit status from the `uname`.

So [ferada’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208345/23408) can be streamlined a bit:

```
if output=$(/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober)  &&  [ -z "$output" ]
    # i.e., if 30_os-prober successfully produced no output
then
    install_linux_only
else
    install_dual_boot
fi
```

Note that it is good practice to use all-upper-case names
only for environment variables
(or variables to be visible throughout the script). 
Variables of limited scope are usually named in lower case
(or, if you prefer, camelCase).

Answer (score 6):

You can assign the value to a variable and then check the exit status as well:

```
PROBE_VALUE=`/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && [ -z "$PROBE_VALUE" ]; then
    install_linux_only
else
    install_dual_boot
fi
```

Comment: Your approach and logic are good, but you seem to have your `then` and `else` branches backwards: based on his words and his second code block, the OP seems to want `install_dual_boot` if the output is **`-n`** or the probe *fails*.

Comment: @Scott Nah, you're right, your solution looks nicer anyway.