# Script to see /mysqlshare is present in all list servers, doing only first iteration

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I need to get `/mysqlshare`details from all the MySQL servers.
I have written a script using a `while read` loop, but it's getting the details of only the first server,

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="/home/mysqladm/server_list/server_list.txt"
# while loop
while IFS= read -r a
do
        # display line or do something on $line
        output=`ssh $a df -h | grep mysqlshare`
#echo $a,$output
echo $a ,$output >> /home/mysqladm/server_list/output.txt
done < "$file"
```

I have `server_list.txt` file in which there are two servers like,

```
server_name1,
server_name2,
```

it's going to server_name1 and doing `df -h` and getting out of script. 
Why is the loop not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  What have you done to try to debug this?  What happens when you comment out the `ssh` and just print the server name?  By the way, you should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$a"` and `"$output"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  Also, just for clarity, you might want to change `\`…\`` to `$(…)` — see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/80216), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838/80216), and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119/80216).  And please indent correctly.

Comment: I am new to scripting, trying from my end to get it.Do loop when we use while read in it? i used ====================================for server in `cat /home/mysqladm/server_list/ms_mysql_all_servers_list` ;   

do

share=`ssh $server df -h /mysqlshare*`
$share >>/home/mysqladm/server_list/share.txt
done...............this one is working fine but unable to get it using while loop.

Answer (score 0):

SSH tries to read all the remaining stdin, so it breaks the loop.
You need to connect it's stdin to null with `< /dev/null` or do something else like that.

Here is how I would write script to achieve that:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=,
file=servers.txt
logfile=log.txt
while read server
do
        ssh $server<<<"df -h | grep mysqlshare" 2>&1>>$logfile
done < $file
```