# Why is one of these date commands valid and the other not?

Tags: options, date-utility

```
[user@mymachine folder]$ echo `date --date=tomorrow +%Y%m%d`
20160802
[user@mymachine folder]$ echo `date -d=tomorrow +%Y%m%d`
date: invalid date `=tomorrow'
```

I'm using Centos 5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Short options are separated from their argument by a space:  `date --date=tomorrow +%Y%m%d`  `date -d tomorrow +%Y%m%d`

Comment: Thank you. Most helpful. I can see that you are correct on my machine.

Comment: @user4556274:  Post that as an answer as it is obviously valid.

Comment: (1) Why are you saying `echo \`date --date=tomorrow +%Y%m%d\`` instead of just `date --date=tomorrow +%Y%m%d`?   (2) If you have a reason to use command substitution, you might want to change `\`…\`` to `$(…)` just for clarity — see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/80216), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838/80216), and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119/80216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short options or unix style options are usually separated from its argument using a space, but space is not strictly required in some cases

For instance

```
echo `date -dtomorrow +%Y%m%d`
```

and

```
echo `date -d tomorrow +%Y%m%d`
```

would work just fine

However in case of,

echo `date -d=tomorrow +%Y%m%d`

`=tomorrow` is considered the argument to `d` but it doesn't make a valid date string