# Command substitution declaration syntax in bash - which of these two is better practice?

Tags: bash, variable, command-substitution

This is part of a bash `find` loop, and I wondered which is more correct syntax and why?

```
filename="$(echo "$i" | cut -c5-)";
filename=`echo "$i" | cut -c5-`;
```

Both function for the purpose of getting the file name.

Comment: You might want to look at http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml. I changed a few things for my own environment, but it will give an excellent starting point.

Comment: That's great; it will help my scripts become much more maintainable and help me get rid of some bad habbits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Bash manual notes that](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell-1):

> The POSIX $() form of command substitution is implemented (see [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)), and preferred to the Bourne shell’s `` (which is also implemented for backwards compatibility).

So `$(...)` is preferred over `` `...` `` in anything new and Bash-specific you're writing¹. Backtick substitution doesn't nest well (you have to escape them), and has some slightly odd quoting behaviour. You can nest `$(... $(...) ...)` arbitrarily much without issue. The manual [describes the behaviour of the two as](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’. The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

It's [usually considered](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) best practice to quote all string expansions to avoid word-splitting issues, including in places where it isn't strictly required, so `"$(...)"` is also better practice here.

Finally, two relevant parts from that [same wooledge page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#line-36):

> - It's also time you forgot about `` `...` ``. It isn't consistent with the syntax of Expansion and is terribly hard to nest without a dose of painkillers. Use `$(...)` instead.
> - And for heaven's sake, "Use more quotes!" Protect your strings and parameter expansions from [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). Word splitting will eat your babies if you don't quote things properly.

¹<sub>Actually, even in POSIX `sh` scripts, these are considered best practice. There are still weaker shells around, but you'll know if you're going to encounter them.</sub>

Comment: In the Bourne-shell family, only the Bourne shell doesn't support `\`...\``. Even the original version of `ash` (initially a free reimplementation of the Bourne shell in 1989) supported `$(...)`.

Comment: Note that it's not only _word splitting_. It's word splitting _and globbing (filename generation)_. Leaving a command/variable substitution unquoted is the split+glob operator. (that operator only applies in _list_ contexts though, so not in the assignment to a scalar variable).

Answer (score 5):

A comment about good-practice in your code not related to `` `...` `` vs `$(...)`:

In

```
filename="$(echo "$i" | cut -c5-)"
```

There are at least 4 potential caveats (minor unless there's an incentive to exploit them):

- You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data as you may get (depending on the `echo` implementation or environment) problems with values of `$i` that start with `-` or contain backslashes. Best is to use `printf` (here `printf '%s\n' "$i"`) when dealing with arbitrary data.
- `cut` and most text filtering utility are not very appropriate for dealing with file paths because they act on *every* line of their input. So here, you're taking the first 4 characters off *every* line of `$i` (newline is as valid a character as any in file names). Best is to use `filename=${i#????}` (though you may also want to take into account cases where `$i` contains fewer than 4 characters).
- command substitution (either `` `...` `` or `$(...)`) removes *every* trailing newline character from the output of the command. So if `$i` ends in newline characters, you'll miss them in `$filename`. `${i#????}` also works around that.
- `cut -c5-` or `${i#????}` removes 4 *characters*. Beware that in some locales, characters can be made of several *bytes*. You may want to take that into account. (also note that [GNU `cut` doesn't support multi-byte characters](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6707) yet (`cut -c` is the same as `cut -b`)).