# Shell, bash, linux ; after variable declaration, why semi-colon and what does it do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is the line.

```
    variable=`ls -A $1 | grep '[abc]'; ls -1 $1`
```

I understand the line before the semi-colon but I do not understand how this line works after semi-colon. Does it

```
  after the command(variable assignment) 
  and then run the command after semi-colon?
```

Then the following line would be same?

```
    variable=`ls -A $1 | grep '[abc]' | ls -1 $1`
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they aren't the same, the latter would pipe `grep` into `ls` (which is almost certainly not what you want). The semicolon simply separates two different commands.

Firstly, you probably want to start using the [newer, more flexible `$( ... )` instead of the backtick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/10762).

Take this as an example:

```
$ var=`echo foo; echo bar`
$ echo "$var"
foo
bar
```

You can think of the backticks (or `$( ... )`) as returning whatever was printed on standard output during the execution of the code contained between them.

In your case, it looks at the output of `ls -A $1` once, and looks for a line in its output containing `a`, `b`, or `c`, and then prints a single column output of `ls -1 $1`. In general this is a bad idea, [you shouldn't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

the semicolon simply separates two consecutive commands.
the manpage (`man bash`) says (in the chapter *Lists*):

> Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially

e.g. the following fill first run the command `foo` and then the command `bar`.

```
foo; bar
```

to parse your example correctly, you first have to build a hierarchical model of it:

```
 variable=`ls -A $1 | grep '[abc]'; ls -1 $1`
```

can be broken down to  `variable=...` (something within back-ticks) and `ls -A $1 | grep '[abc]'; ls -1 $1` (the thing within backticks).

backticks are used get the output of a command (see the *Command substitution* in `man bash`); so you are assigning the output of the entire `ls -A $1 | grep '[abc]'; ls -1 $1` to the variable.

the output of the substutited command is the list of files matching a certain pattern (including hidden hildes) appended with the full list of files (whatever that can be used for...)