# How do I read the output of commands in a script

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

I'm learning Linux scripting at the moment, and one thing I can get working is assigning a command output to a variable. The command `service httpd configtest` returns `Syntax is OK`, so I wrote this.

```
#!/bin/bash

var=`service httpd configtest`
echo "Output is $var"
```

From what I've read that should store the output in `var`, then echo it. However, the output when I run that script is

```
Syntax OK
Output is
```

What have I done wrong? I'm using CentOS 6.5 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `service httpd configtest`, it actually run command `apachectl configtest`:

```
  ....
  apachectl=/usr/sbin/apachectl  
  ....
  graceful|help|configtest|fullstatus)
        $apachectl $@
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
  ....
```

Do a `strace`:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=write apachectl configtest
Process 22999 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 22999 resumed (parent 22998 ready)
[pid 22999] write(1, "1024\n", 5)       = 5
Process 22999 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 23000 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 23000 resumed (parent 22998 ready)
Process 22998 suspended
[pid 23000] write(2, "Syntax OK\n", 10Syntax OK
) = 10
Process 22998 resumed
Process 23000 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

You can see, the output `Syntax OK` is written to `stderr`, causes the ouput can not save to `var` variable.

You can make it done, by redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
var=$(service httpd configtest 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the `service httpd configtest` is outputting to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. You could try:

```
var=$(service httpd configtest 2>&1)
echo "Output is $var"
```

Or even this, without the variable:

```
echo -n "Output is "
service httpd configtest 2>&1
```

The `-n` option to echo suppresses the newline at the end so that the output of `service httpd configtest` will be on the same line.

Also note I have switched the backticks (`` `...` ``) for `$(...)` above since backticks can cause some problems and are generally considered deprecated. See [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff) for more information.

For more information on what `stdout` and `stderr` are and what `2>&1` does, check out the Wikipedia pages on [Standard Streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) and [Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28Unix%29).

Comment: See also: [What are the shell’s control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `var` contains [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that causes it to move a line up.

Your output can be reproduced with the following example:

```
var=$'\033[FSyntax OK\n'
echo "Output is $var"
```

This produces:

```
Syntax OK
Output is
```

where the first line overwrites the prompt from which the script (containing the above two lines was started).