# How do I handle special characters like a bracket in a bash script?

Tags: shell, quoting

I am trying to get the output of some programs and assign them to variables. I am using backticks to do it, but I can switch to a different method if necessary. What I notice is that often I do not get the expected output in the variable. A simple case is this below. The actual examples I have are more complicated. Whatever the output from the program I'm running in the backticks I want it in the variable. Is that possible?

```
test=`echo [asdf]`
```

If I `echo $test` it shows just a.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. [Don't use backticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff), use `$()`.
2. Use single quotes around literal strings and [double around variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells/171347#171347), so `echo "$test"`.
3. [Don't use `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), use `printf`.

After all:

```
    $ test="$(printf '%s' '[asdf]')"
    $ printf "%s\n" "$test"
    [asdf]
```

Comment: Yeah I mean the `echo` was just an example, the actual commands are more complicated. I will try what you suggested, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest answer is to escape the `[` so that it isn't treated as a special pattern character. (The closing `]` is treated literally if it isn't preceded by an unquoted `[`.)

```
test=$(echo \[asdf])
```