# find matching files in one directory and sub directories

Tags: find

I have used Percona XtraBackup to create a compressed backup, but now I need to decompress the files. The instructions say I should run:

```
for bf in `find . -iname "*\.qp"`; do qpress -d $bf $(dirname $bf) && rm $bf; done
```

but this looks like it is going to search everywhere and decompress any files it finds. I only want it to only decompress the files in one specific directory and its subdirectories.

I tried running:

```
for bf in `find . -iname "/path/to/my/directory/*.qp"`; do qpress -d $bf $(dirname $bf) && rm $bf; done
```

But this gave the error:

```
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  
That means that '-iname `/path/to/my/directory/*.qp'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: instead of `find .`, try `find /path/to/my/directory/` and so, `-iname '*.qp'`

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tell you where is the error. No filenames ending with `/directory/*.qp` exists. The `-iname` parameter is about proper file name, not path.

So you should precede the command with `cd /path/to/my/directory/` or write the find command as `find /path/to/my/directory/ -iname "*.qp"` which is what you want: starting from that directory, check all filename matching the `*.qp`.

Comment: cheers, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for bf in `find . -iname "*\.qp"`; do qpress -d $bf $(dirname $bf) && rm $bf; done
>
> for bf in `find . -iname "/path/to/my/directory/*.qp"`; do qpress -d $bf $(dirname $bf) && rm $bf; done
> ```

Both of these commands have a number of problems.  Most obviously, they fail to handle unusual filenames, both by looping over the output of `find` and by failing to quote variables.

Then, of course, there's the fact that a filename will never contain a slash, as noted in the error you got.

---

What you want is:

```
find /path/to/my/directory -type f -iname '*.qp' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do qpress -d "$f" "$(dirname "$f")" && rm "$f"; done' find-sh {} +
```

Or, an alternate version with line breaks:

```
find /path/to/my/directory -type f -iname '*.qp' -exec sh -c '
  for f
  do
    qpress -d "$f" "${f%/*}" &&
      rm "$f"
  done' find-sh {} +
```

---

Further reading:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)
- [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/135943)

Comment: cheers for that, as a bit of a Linux newbie there's a lot of very useful information there. It'l take a while for me to fully digest it though. . .