# Why is attempting to capture a PID causing my shell script to mysteriously terminate?

Tags: shell-script, shell, centos, process

I'm using CentOS 7.  I"m trying to capture the "master PID" of a process in a script variable.  This is my script

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

PID="$APP_ROOT/shared/pids/puma.pid"
echo "before ..."
MASTER_PID=`pgrep -f '^([^ ]*/)?puma '`
echo "after ..."
xxx
```

However, the word "after ..." is never printed out.  There's something about this line

```
MASTER_PID=`pgrep -f '^([^ ]*/)?puma '`
```

which is causing things to behave badly, especially if there is no puma process running.  Does anyone know a way to rewrite the above so that I can capture my master PID or at least allow execution to pass to the next line if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Do you understand what `set -e` does?

Comment: ... and have you consulted the `EXIT STATUS` section of `man pgrep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `set -e`, then you need to keep pgrep from failing, by:

```
MASTER_PID=`pgrep -f '^([^ ]*/)?puma ' || true`
```

Comment: Consider telling him also that using `$( .. )` instead of backticks might be better.

Comment: I think you just did! :) it was tangential to the core question, so I didn’t. There may be other improvements to what they’re doing, too. For command substitution differences, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/117549

Answer (score 1):

`set -e`  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Since `pgrep` fails when there is no matching `PID`, you are not able to execute `echo "after"` statement.

I think, removing `set -e` should solve your problem.