# Unexpected grep behaviour when using command substituiton

Tags: bash, grep, base64

I'm trying to find and print out all the files that contain a base64 encoded string, using `grep` and command substitution.

If I first encode the base64 string, and then grep, I'm able to find the file:

```
$ echo "FLAG" | base64
RkxBRwo=

$ grep -nr "Rkx"
test.txt:1:RkxBR3tUaGl6STVUaDNGbDRnfQo=
```

But when I use command substitution I get no ouput.

```
$ grep -nr `echo "FLAG" | base64`
```

Comment: Does `test.txt` actually contain `RkxBRwo=`? you've only shown that it contains `RkxBR3tUaGl6STVUaDNGbDRnfQo=`

Comment: You seem to be showing your shell prompt (`$ `) at the beginning of your output lines (e.g., `$ RkxBRwo=`). That doesn’t make sense, and is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steeldriver posted the answer as a comment, so I’m posting it as an answer. 
`echo "FLAG" | base64` outputs `RkxBRwo=`,
so your

```
grep -nr `echo "FLAG" | base64`
```

command
is doing

```
grep -nr RkxBRwo=
```

But, based on what you’ve showed,
your `test.txt` file doesn’t contain `RkxBRwo=`;
it contains `RkxBR` (followed by other characters).

If you want to search your files
for the first 5 characters of the base64 encoding of `FLAG`,
do

```
grep -nr `echo "FLAG" | base64 | cut -c1-5`
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I haven't seen the `=` added as base64 padding at the end of the "FLAG" output. I was basically grepping for something that did not exist in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
grep -nr `echo "FLAG" | base64`
```

says to search recursively in all files in the current directory for pattern returned by the command `echo "FLAG" | base64`.

Instead, I believe you want

```
echo "FLAG" | base64 | grep -n 'Rkx'
```

or, if for whatever reason you need a command substitution:

```
grep -n 'Rkx' <<< $(echo "FLAG" | base64)
```

Notice the expression `$()` is used instead of backticks for command substitution. [Here is why.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/80886)