# Bash script curl input variable from command line

Tags: bash, curl

I would like to be able to pass in what environment when script is run. Like `script.sh dev` (`$dev` would populate appropriate URL in curl command in script).
Maybe even print the environment as options to pass?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Environment/URL
dev=myurl.myco.com
tst=myurl.myco.com
tst02=myurl.myco.com
tst03=myurl.myco.com
qa01=myurl.myco.com

request=`curl -L -k -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'cache-control:no-cache' -X  https://$tst/bla/bla/bla/bla 2>/dev/null`
```

Comment: You could use a `case .. esac` statement checking the value of a positional parameter such as `$1`, or you could use a `select` statement to present a list of options if one is not provided.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bash, you may make use of associative arrays (introduced in `bash-4.0-alpha`<sup>1</sup>).

You can define the `script`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A urls

urls[dev]=dev.example.com
urls[tst]=test.example.com

request="$(curl ...  https://"${urls["$1"]}"/foo/bar ...)"
```

And invoke it as:

```
script dev
```

The first positional parameter (`$1`) will be used as the key for retrieving a URL from the `urls` array.

As a (more user friendly) variation, as [suggested by DopeGhoti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518919/bash-script-curl-input-variable-from-command-line#comment958833_518919), `script` may be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A urls

urls[dev]=dev.example.com
urls[tst]=test.example.com

select opt in "${!urls[@]}"; do
    [ ! -z "$opt" ] && break
done

request="$(curl ... https://"${urls["$opt"]}"/foo/bar ...)"
```

Which is meant to be invoked as:

```
script
```

The `select` command presents the user with the list of the keys defined for the `urls` array and ensures that a valid key is chosen.

Finally, as a way to separate concerns, you may store your URLs in a plain text file, here named `urlfile`, formatted as:

```
dev dev.example.com
tst test.example.com
```

and load its content into the `script`'s `urls` array with a `read` loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A urls

while read -r label url; do
    urls["$label"]="$url"
done <urlfile

select opt in "${!urls[@]}"; do
    [ ! -z "$opt" ] && break
done

request="$(curl ... https://"${urls["$opt"]}"/foo/bar ...)"
```

Note: even if not necessary, I chose the `$(...)` command substitution syntax (instead of `` ` ` ``)
because it is [generally more versatile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>With this [commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/NEWS?h=bash-4.0-alpha) from 2011. Bash 4.0+ is now widely available.</sub>