# Command Substitution Within a Command Substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I'm new to shell scripting and wanted to insure I haven't made any errors in creating this script for making a `borg` backup to a flashdrive that I plug into my computer.

- Does the below script look solid? (I made it executable and put it in my `/usr/local/bin/`)
- I added the "date" command substitution within the "borg" command substitution. Is this allowed? Are there any rules that frown on putting command substitutions within command substitutions?
- Does the entire line need quotes (") around it, like I have done?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$(borg create /media/$USER/Flashdrive/backup::$(date +%FT%H%M) /home/$USER/Documents)"
```

Comment: The ability to be easily nested is one of the reasons often given for preferring this form of command substitution over the older "backtick" form. See for example [What's the difference between $(stuff) and ` stuff `?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff)

Comment: The `echo` and the first command substitution are not needed (but the outer quotes around the command substitution would be correct). And `borg` allows a few placeholders in the archive name, so you could write the date as `{now:%Y-%m-%dT%H%M}` (maybe `%F` instead of `%Y-%m-%d` works too, I just haven't seen an example in the [manual](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html)).

Comment: Why did you use curly braces: {now:%FT%M%H}. instead of $(now:%FT%M%H)?

Comment: Freddy, would you mind posting as an answer? If I understand you, you recommended this formatting:  borg create /media/$USER/Flashdrive/backup::"$(date +%FT%H%M)" /home/$USER/Documents

Comment: Why are you using `echo`? Rather than ``echo $(borg …)``, why not just run the `borg …` command?

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok.  You can easily try it by replacing borg with echo and see if this is what you are looking for.

Double quotes are not required.

Comment: Replace borg with echo? Like this: echo $(echo create /media...)

Comment: Yes, and you'll see the output right the way - without being afraid by whatever borg might  do.