# For loop and locate command with regular expression mismatched

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, for, locate

when I change any configuration I made a copy of the original file with suffix .original. Now I am composing a simple script that will find all *.original files and work with both versions, ie with and without .original suffix.

I do use command `locate` with regular expression to avoid mismatched files with the `original` string in the middle of the path.

My command is `locate --regex ^.*\\.original$` that works perfectly `in terminal`. It finds all files that ends with the .original suffix such as `file.original`

**However** when I use the same command `in bash script` in the `for loop` it returns me variants such as `file.original` `file-original` `file_original` etc.

> How should I modify the regex or for loop to get only .original files?

My shell is:

```
$ echo $BASH
/usr/bin/bash
```

My bash script is:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Plain locate command:"
locate --regex ^.*\\.original$ | grep test

echo "For loop:"
for file in `locate --regex ^.*\\.original$ | grep test`; do
        echo $file
done
```

You can use this for testing:

```
mkdir /tmp/test 
touch /tmp/test/file.original
touch /tmp/test/file-original
touch /tmp/test/file_original
updatedb
locate --regex ^.*\\.original$
```

In my terminal it will find:

```
/tmp/test/file.original
```

But my script will find:

```
Plain locate command:
/tmp/test/file.original
For loop:
/tmp/test/file-original
/tmp/test/file.original
/tmp/test/file_original
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backticks require more escaping. This is one of the reasons you should prefer `$()` (see e.g. "backslash fun" in this answer: [*What's the difference between `$(stuff)` and `` `stuff` ``?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/108618)).

Due to not enough escaping inside the backticks, the dot you wanted to escape is unescaped when the string is ultimately interpreted as regex.

Change the relevant line to:

```
for file in $(locate --regex '^.*\.original$' | grep test); do
```

Notes:

- I used single-quoting to conveniently handle the backslash *and* the asterisk. In your original code the unquoted and unescaped asterisk can trigger the [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).
- `^.*` in the regex changes nothing. Single-quoted `\.original$` would be enough. I decided to keep `^.*` only to point out the possibility of filename expansion.
- Get used to [quoting variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) (e.g. `echo "$file"`). The linked answer recommends quoting `$()` as well, but in our `for` loop quoting would be wrong. Not quoting `$()` is also wrong. Both are wrong because…
- In general **building `for` loops like this is often wrong**. It's the [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). To do something with the output of `locate` better pipe it to `xargs`, preferably as null-terminated strings:

  ```
  locate -0 … | grep -z … | xargs -r0 …
  ```

  These options are not portable.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for the valuable notes! There is still too much to learn... ;)