# How to assign value using echo to a variable but don't display it in terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo

My bash script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo $i | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
    cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.py "$i".py
done
```

If i write `A B.py C D.py`, this script will turn it into `A.py B.py C.py D.py` 
`-v` flag of `cp -v` explains what is being done

but i **don't want to print** the edited filenames `echo $i`. It's annoying.

How can i do that? 
alternative solutions are also appreciated

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    var=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')
    cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.py "$var".py
done
```

Comment: isn't there any better solution? just assigning value to `$i` variable

Comment: I edit my answer, try this out

Comment: still shows.. i'm on parrot os

Comment: I reedited my answer, hope this one will suit you

Comment: i came up with a solution similar to yours. I want to keep my code optimized. So i will use @they 's one

Comment: the trick is called command substitution, and for [various reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff), [it's better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/170373) to use the `$()` syntax than backticks. Also you need to quote the arg to `echo` to avoid [various issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767) with the shell's word splitting and filename globbing.

Answer (score 3):

You want to trim the value of `$i` after the last dot in the string.

You can do this like so:

```bsh
i=${i%.*}
```

This removes the shortest suffix string from `$i` that matches the filename globbing pattern `.*` (a dot followed by any string).

If you know you want to trim off `.py` specifically:

```bsh
i=${i%.py}
```

This means you could write your `cp` command like so:

```bsh
cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.py "${i%.py}.py"
```

This would be the only command in the loop body and it would remove the `.py` filename suffix from `$i`, if the value had such a suffix, and then add `.py`. This ensures that the destination filename always has `.py` as the filename suffix and at the same time avoids doubling the suffix.

---

Suggestion for script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for string do
    cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.py "${string%.py}.py"
done
```

Or,

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

for string; cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.py $string:r.py
```

... which uses the `zsh` shell, its alternative, shorter, form for the `for` loop, and its `:r` modifier to remove the filename extension before adding `.py` to the name.

You would call either script like so:

```bsh
./script A B.py C D.py
```

Comment: oh so much better.. thank you